# com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 12500 ISSUE

Tags: android, ios, flutter, authentication, google-signin

Edit: This worked - the only thing that did

> I searched for what this means and realized that it has something to do with Firebase console configuration. Actually, you need to add SHA-1 or SHA-256 fingerprint of the app signing certificate in Firebase console to use this Google Sign-in feature. However, Internal App Sharing uses its own certificate for app signing that is different from the original app signing certificate. As a result, you need to add the fingerprint of Internal App Sharing certificate to Firebase console. You can find it in Development tools > Internal app sharing > APP CERTIFICATE tab in Google Play Store. I tested it and everything was okay!

I am getting this error when signing in with google using firebase in flutter. There is another similar question - already tried all answers none worked

**Things I have done**

- Added a support email
- Generated a sha1 and sha256 using the command

  `keytool -list -v -keystore <keystore path>`
- Configured Oauth screen in google cloud - so added a support email there too and set email users to external
- Using my actual phone as an emulator, so it does have google play installed

**Images & Code**

Oauth Screen:
[image]

Firebase Sha1
[image]

Code (shortened):

```
 final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();

      final GoogleSignInAccount? googleSignInAccount =
          await googleSignIn.signIn().catchError(
            (onError) => throw(onError)
          );

      if (googleSignInAccount != null) {
        final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication =
            await googleSignInAccount.authentication;

        final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
          accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken,
          idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken,
        );

        try {
          final UserCredential userCredential =
              await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
} on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
          if (e.code == 'account-exists-with-different-credential') {
            print('The account already exists with a different credential.');
          } else if (e.code == 'invalid-credential') {
            print('Error occurred while accessing credentials. Try again.');
          }
        } catch (e) {
          print(e);
        }
```

Comment: Try to check below post if it can solve your problem
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47632035/google-sign-in-error-12500?rq=2