# result_canceled using google fit api

Tags: android, api, google-fit

Can't connect to the google api, the result on the monitor is:

***E/GoogleFit: RESULT_CANCELED*** (this message only appears after select the google account)

Obviously, i have the internet permission on my app.

on the google developer console, the name of the package is the same of my project.

Here is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnDataPointListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener{

private static final int REQUEST_OAUTH = 1;
private static final String AUTH_PENDING = "auth_state_pending";
private boolean authInProgress = false;
private GoogleApiClient mApiClient;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if(savedInstanceState != null){
        authInProgress = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(AUTH_PENDING);
    }


    mApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Fitness.SENSORS_API)
            .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_ACTIVITY_READ_WRITE))
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this).addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build(); {
    }

}


@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mApiClient.connect();

}



@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    DataSourcesRequest dataSourcesRequest = new DataSourcesRequest.Builder()
            .setDataTypes(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_CUMULATIVE)
            .setDataSourceTypes(DataSource.TYPE_RAW)
            .build();
    ResultCallback<DataSourcesResult> dataSourcesResultResultCallback = new ResultCallback<DataSourcesResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(@NonNull DataSourcesResult dataSourcesResult) {
            for(DataSource dataSource : dataSourcesResult.getDataSources()){
                if(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_CUMULATIVE.equals(dataSource.getDataType())){
                    registerFitnessDataListener(dataSource, DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_CUMULATIVE);
                }
            }
        }
    };
    Fitness.SensorsApi.findDataSources(mApiClient, dataSourcesRequest).setResultCallback(dataSourcesResultResultCallback);



}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    if(!authInProgress){
        try{
            authInProgress = true;
            connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(MainActivity.this, REQUEST_OAUTH);

        }catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e){

        }
    }else{
        Log.e("GoogleFit", "AuthInProgress");
    }

}

@Override
public void onDataPoint(DataPoint dataPoint) {
    for(final Field field: dataPoint.getDataType().getFields()){
        final Value value = dataPoint.getValue(field);
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Field"+field.getName()+"Value:"+ value,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }


}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == REQUEST_OAUTH){
        authInProgress = false;
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            if(!mApiClient.isConnecting() && !mApiClient.isConnected()){
                mApiClient.connect();
            }
        }else if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){
            Log.e("GoogleFit", "RESULT_CANCELED");
        }
    }else {
        Log.e("GoogleFit", "requestCode NOT request_oauth");
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


}

private void registerFitnessDataListener(DataSource dataSource, DataType dataType){
    SensorRequest request = new SensorRequest.Builder()
            .setDataSource(dataSource)
            .setDataType(dataType)
            .setSamplingRate(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build();

    Fitness.SensorsApi.add(mApiClient, request, this)
            .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
                    if(status.isSuccess()){
                        Log.e("GoogleFit", "SensorApi succesfully added");
                    }
                }
            });
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    Fitness.SensorsApi.remove(mApiClient, this)
            .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
                    if(status.isSuccess()){
                        mApiClient.disconnect();
                    }
                }
            });
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState, PersistableBundle outPersistentState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState, outPersistentState);
    outState.putBoolean(AUTH_PENDING, authInProgress);
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

**Fixed problem:**

Well, i've made some investigations and I found a solution.

The code is working good, the problem was on the OAuthClient.

**Steps to avoid the problem:**

**Step 1:**

Go to Google development console and enable the API (Fitness API in my case),it's very important i this step, to make ensure that you create the OAuth credentials, just use the command given and write the SHA1

**Step 2:**

Go to Firebase Console and follow the steps

**Step 3:**

Download the JSON and put in your app folder (in your project)

**Step 4:**

Create a metadata like this in the manifest:

```
 <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="-key of your JSON-" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Hope it helps for the others! this solution worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are using the correct [OAuth 2.0 Client ID](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/get-api-key) code. This may lead to an error if you're using it wrong. Also make sure that you have updated the authentication flow based from the latest [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in#before_you_begin) for Google Sign-In.

You may refer with these SO threads: [Google Oauth 2.0 RESULT_CANCELED while using Google Fit api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37289028/google-oauth-2-0-result-canceled-while-using-google-fit-api) and [GoogleApiClient not connecting while using google fit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37679476/googleapiclient-not-connecting-while-using-google-fit).