# Google Fit on Android is working on debug but not on production

Tags: google-fit

I am using History API to get user steps. It's working on debug but not on production.

I had created two certificates on *OAuth 2.0 Client* for both debug and production apps.

Unfortunately, I can get the steps in debug app, but not in the production signed app.

The app is not published for public yet. It's still in the internal testing. It's of course signed with production key.

When running the app, it shows Google authentication dialog so users can select Google account to be used for authentication. Upon selecting account, it shows error:
`com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 4: The user must be signed in to make this API call.`

Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully [✓this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37289028/google-oauth-2-0-result-canceled-while-using-google-fit-api) saved my time.

Basically, when your app using "**App Signing**", you need to check the **SHA1** used by "App Signing", *not* the one mentioned on the official Google Fit documentation as release certificate.