# ERROR. 'keytool' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: android, facebook, android-studio, sdk

I try to add facebook login to my android app. I exactly followed the documentation but when I try to run a command line in Android Studio terminal to generate a development hash key, it says "'keytool' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

This is my command code:

> keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore
>   %HOMEPATH%.android\debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl
>   base64

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Click on the gradle tab on the right hand side of android studio and navigate to :app and click on tasks -> android and run the signing report to get the hash key for your app, like this:

[image]

Comment: I did. And now it says "Missing keystore"

Comment: @Anishahbazyan have you generated the keystore?

Comment: No. Where should I generate it?

Comment: @Anishahbazyan check this link for more reference how to get your debug keystore. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16965058/where-is-debug-keystore-in-android-studio

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `<JDK location>\bin` to `PATH` environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

`keytool` ships with Android Studio as part of the JRE needed to run Android Studio itself.

For Windows its: `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\keytool.exe`

For Mac its: `/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/keytool`

Add this to your environment variables then run the keytool command again.