# Confusion on how to use "IdToken" properly

Tags: android, firebase, oauth-2.0, google-api, firebase-authentication

I have been trying to implement an `OAuth 2.0` authentication process into my app.

We have a backend server with REST API, fully coded in Java and with Spring integrated.

The app is registered on `Firebase` (I can access it through the Console) and I have successfully implemented the `Google SignIn` process and the `Email/Password` (users get added in my userbase as displayed in the Firebase Console).

My problem here is most probably my poor understanding of the OAuth process: as I understand it, I am supposed to use `FirebaseUser.getIdToken(bool)` from within the app to get the `JWT` (JSON Web Token) that I send over (through `HTTP Post`) to the backend server for a user-request that would require authentication (something such as sending an information that our server should save in our User-Database in the row related to the UID associated with the user sending the request).

I believe [this doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens) is the one I'm supposed to follow to achieve my goal. However, this part of the code snippets presented in the doc leaves me confused:

```
FirebaseUser mUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
mUser.getIdToken(true)
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<GetTokenResult>() {
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<GetTokenResult> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                String idToken = task.getResult().getToken();
                // Send token to your backend via HTTPS
                // ...
            } else {
                // Handle error -> task.getException();
            }
        }
    });
```

1. The `idToken` I'm getting is 1232 chars long. Am I obligated to send the whole String? The structure looks like this: `{alg,kid}.{iss,name,picture,aud,auth_time,user_id,sub,iat,exp,email,email_verified,firebase{...}}.XXX`. There are quite a few fields that I would trim down since I won't be using them on the server-side.
2. I can't seem to get the "XXX" part right of my idToken for now. I know it's related to a digital signature and that I probably need a Public Key, and a Private Key (not quite sure where to get the good ones yet). How do I deal with that?
3. What might the `// Send token to your backend via HTTPS` look like (a simple URL containing the String, or is there a proper way to send the JWT)?
4. Is the JWT all the server needs to receive from the client for the authentication process?
5. Can I send additional information with the JWT (such as what the authentication should do once it is verified)? If not, should I assume that that is done after the server replies back to the client that it is now waiting for a request from the now-authenticated user?
6. I've seen people calling some URL to verify their token but I'm uncertain which URL I should use, which token I should pass in it, and what I should expect as a result. Maybe `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=1/fFBGRNJru1FQd44AzqT3Zg` or `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token=XYZ123`?
7. What is the role of the `Admin SDK` in all that?

I thought I was over and that this was all I needed until I stumbled upon [this other doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) which brings other questions:

1. <s>Does `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:6.3.0'` only need to be in the server-side code?</s> **Apparently yes!**
2. Where do I plug my `firebase-adminsdk.json` file in all that? **In the Firebase Admin SDK set up code provided by Google.**
3. `FileInputStream serviceAccount = new FileInputStream("path/to/serviceAccountKey.json");` and `FileInputStream refreshToken = new FileInputStream("path/to/refreshToken.json");`: which JSON file do I plug in there? **The one mentioned just above!**
4. Does my server need to have the `google_services.json` integrated?
5. This seems to mostly be talking about using Firebase's `Database`. Is it doable to use my own DB (it's a MySQL hosted on GoDaddy)? **Yes!**

I'm so sorry if that's a lot of questions. I'm a bit new around here.