# Google login failed when using new firebase app and it is working well for old firebase apps

Tags: android, firebase, authentication, google-signin

I need to change firebase app in android app, But when chaning it I have this error

Google sign in failed

```
com.google.android.gms.tasks.RuntimeExecutionException: com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 12500: 
    at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu.getResult(Unknown Source)
```

- I added **sh1**
- Enable google loging method
- Using last updated firebase versions

  `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0'`

  `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:18.1.0'`

  `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'`

add plugin to the end of the build gradle app level

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

add google services in gradle progject level

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'
```

Any one can help?
Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google sign in failed com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47619229/google-sign-in-failed-com-google-android-gms-common-api-apiexception-10)

Comment: I made all of these solutions, But The android app is already working well in any old firebase project, But when creating new one and try using it the above mention error is appeared

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The app was working well in old firebase projects, but in new firebase projects we had to add the logo of the app in the gcp console and it is working well, the firebase support who is suggest this solution.

Thanks!