# GoogleSignIn ApiException: 10

Tags: android, kotlin, google-oauth, google-signin

I'm using google auth in my app but I can't get it to work. My currently error is

> com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: 
>           at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.ApiExceptionUtil.fromStatus(Unknown Source)
>           at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(Unknown Source)
>           at br.com.etc.login.LoginActivity.onActivityResult(LoginActivity.kt:123)

My LoginActivity:

```
class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var googleSignInClient: GoogleSignInClient? = null
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)

        val gso = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.google_client_id))
            .build()

        googleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso)

         bt_login_google.onClick {
            val signInIntent = googleSignInClient!!.signInIntent
            startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN)
        }
     }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            val task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data)
            handleSignInResult(task)
        } 
    }

    private fun handleSignInResult(completedTask: Task<GoogleSignInAccount>) {
        try {
            val account = completedTask.getResult(ApiException::class.java)
            vm.loginGoogle(account?.idToken ?: "")
        } catch (e: ApiException) {
            Snackbar.make((findViewById(android.R.id.content)), R.string.error_generic, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show()
            Timber.e(e)
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting my SHA1 doing from Gradle>App>tasks>android>signinReport
[image: Android Studio, Gradle Menu]

I added my SHA1 to https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials now looks like this:
[image: Google Console Panel]

My (R.string.google_client_id) is the Client ID

So I went to my firebase project (I'm only using for the analytics), went to project settings and added the SHA1. I also added a support email.
I downloaded the google-settings.json and added to my project. 
IDk if it's important but my app is not published, I don't have a google developer account.

I know this is a common question but I tried everything I could think of and I'm still having stuck with this problem.

Comment: Did you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47619229/google-sign-in-failed-com-google-android-gms-common-api-apiexception-10 ?

Comment: @Orange yes, but I don't have a Google Play account yet

Answer (score 1):

you should generate a Web Client ID under OAuth 2.0 client IDs instead of using the Android one