# Google Sign-In with backend server fails with com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, google-authentication

I'm stuck on this `com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10` issue and I can't find why.
I searched a lot in SO and Google/Firebase doc but it does not help me. I think I'm in a specific configuration need:

- I have an Android app setup with a Firebase and a Google developer projects (project id `project-foobar`)
- there is an external Google developer project `project-baz` in which there is an OAuth 2 clientId of type Web application
- I want to use the external `project-baz` clientId in my Android app because this project belongs to another company which takes care of the OAuth Consent Screen process
- I need to request an id token to give it to a backend server (as described [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth))

So this is my current setup:

1. I set up my Android app in Firebase with its package name and keystore SHA-1 fingerprint in the Settings > General screen.
2. I enabled `Google` in Firebase Authentication > Sign-in methods with the Web SDK configuration from `project-baz`
3. I downloaded the `google-services.json` file in Firebase Settings > General screen and pasted it in the Android project
4. My app calls this:

```
val signInOptions = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
    .requestEmail()
    .requestIdToken(context.getString(R.string.project_baz_client_id))
    .build()
val client = GoogleSignIn.getClient(context, signInOptions)
startActivityForResult(client.signInIntent, REQUEST_SIGN_IN)
```

The problem is I receive this exception `com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10`

Any idea?

Edit: I forgot to mention the auth process works fine if I use the OAuth 2 clientId from `project-foobar`

Comment: My setup is different but I started getting this same error two days ago in production.

Comment: Made mine work - Added the client ids of my prod and debug builds from GCP to Firebase in the list of Whitelisted client ids.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47620437/10752944 Make sure you have added this

Comment: @AdityaKushwaha I also did that but it doesn't help

Comment: @Kartik the SHA-1 fingerprint is set up correctly, I checked several time. And the `google-services.json` file is up-to-date. About the Google Play link in the Firebase project settings, my app is not yet published in the Play Store, so I can't do that