# Sign In Google with Android not working error while connecting

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Hi i am having a problem with my the google connexion.  Every time that the code is executed it goes in to the catch. I dont know why. I followed the steps from the Google tutorial and saw manyq questions related to that on stack but still not help me to solve this issue. Whe the code is runned it goes in to the catch and it shows the toast that i made. " error while .. ".

Here is what it looks like. I am posting the whole code for the authentification so everyone can analyze it and give me a solution if possible .

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
        mGoogleSignInClient= GoogleSignIn.getClient(this,gso);

        signInButton=(SignInButton)findViewById(R.id.googleButton);
        signInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
                startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
            }
        });
        //pour google
        mAuthStateListener=new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser mFireBaseUser=mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if(mFireBaseUser != null){
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"you are logged in",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent i= new Intent(LoginActivity.this, PrayersEvents.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"please login",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        };
        btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String email=emailId.getText().toString();
                String pwd=password.getText().toString();
                if (email.isEmpty()) {
                    emailId.setError("Please enter email");
                    emailId.requestFocus();
                }
                else if(pwd.isEmpty()){
                    password.setError("Please enter your password");
                    password.requestFocus();
                }
                else if(email.isEmpty() || pwd.isEmpty()){
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Fields are empty!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else if(!(email.isEmpty() && pwd.isEmpty())){
                    mFirebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,pwd).addOnCompleteListener(LoginActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            if(!task.isSuccessful()){
                                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Login error!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            }
                            else{
                                Intent intoHome=new Intent(LoginActivity.this, PrayersEvents.class);
                                startActivity(intoHome);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Error ocurred!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }
        });
        tvSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intoSignUp=new Intent(LoginActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intoSignUp);
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        GoogleSignInAccount account=GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this);
        if(account !=null){
            startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, CreateEvent.class));
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
            try {
                // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
                GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
                Log.d("MON_TAG", account.toString());
                firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
            } catch (ApiException e) {
                // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"error while logging in",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Log.w("errorMsg","Google sign in failed", e);
                // ...
            }
        }
    }

    private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {//acct means account
        Log.d("MON_TAG", "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + acct.getId());
        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
        mFirebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                            Log.d("MON_TAG", "signInWithCredential:success");
                            FirebaseUser user = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                            startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, CreateEvent.class));
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"You are now connected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            GoogleSignInAccount account=GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(getApplicationContext());
                            if(account !=null){
                                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, CreateEvent.class));
                            }
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Could not log in user",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
```

Comment: What does `Log.w("errorMsg","Google sign in failed", e);` log as the value of `e`?

Comment: it shows , W/errorMsg: Google sign in failed
    com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: Searching for that error message, leads me to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47619229/google-sign-in-failed-com-google-android-gms-common-api-apiexception-10

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't instanciate the GoogleApiClient object..

try this code .. it worked for me ..

```
//a constant for detecting the login intent result
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 234;

    //Tag for the logs optional
    private static final String TAG = "YoussefIslem";

    //creating a GoogleSignInClient object
    GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;

    GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;

    CallbackManager mCallbackManager;

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.web_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

        googleApiClient =new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this,this)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API,gso)
                .build();

        //Then we will get the GoogleSignInClient object from GoogleSignIn class
        mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);

        findViewById(R.id.googleContinue).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                signIn();
            }
        });
}

 private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
        Log.d(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + acct.getId());

        //getting the auth credential
        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);

        //Now using firebase we are signing in the user here
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");
                            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "User Signed In", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();

                        } else {
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }

                        // ...
                    }
                });
    }


    //this method is called on click
    private void signIn() {
        //getting the google signin intent
        Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
        googleApiClient.clearDefaultAccountAndReconnect();

        //starting the activity for result
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }



 @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        //if the requestCode is the Google Sign In code that we defined at starting
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {

            //Getting the GoogleSignIn Task
            Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
            try {
                //Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
                GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);

                //authenticating with firebase
                firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
            } catch (ApiException e) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"I'm here"+ e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
}
```