# Unable to sign-in using Google in Android App

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-signin

I've tried many solutions mentioned here but I'm still unable to fix this. I'm receiving:

**"Google sign in failed. com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10"**

I've verified my ***OAuth auto-generated 'web client key' in Google Cloud Console is same*** as what I'm using in my code. But I'm getting the same error. I've also verified that project name is same in Google Cloud Console and Firebase.

Here's my code:

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

  private GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;
  private FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
  private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 1;
  static LoginActivity loginActivity;
  private FirebaseUser currentUser;

  public static LoginActivity getInstance(){
    return loginActivity;
  }
  public FirebaseUser getCurrentUser() {
    return currentUser;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new 
    GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

    mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    View signInButton = findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
    signInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
            startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
        }
    });
 }

 @Override
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        //Here resultCode is 0 & requestCode is 1.  
        Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
        try {
            // This line of code is throwing exception.
            GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
            Log.w(TAG, task.getException());
            Log.d(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + account.getId());
            firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account.getIdToken());
        } catch (ApiException e) {
            // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
            Log.w(TAG, "Google sign in failed", e);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm following [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin) tutorial from official docs. Any help is appreciated.

P.S. I'm also using Firestore database in the same project. And I've successfully saved the google-services.json in the **app's** folder.

Comment: That's most likely because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51360250/firebase-ui-authentication-with-google-fails-with-message-code10-message10/51360406).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you add your SHA1 to the firebase project and  Make sure you complete `Android Device Check API` requirements. This will enable your devices to be recognized. use https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/androidcheck.googleapis.com?project=capital-insider&folder=&organizationId=https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/androidcheck.googleapis.com?project=capital-insider&folder=&organizationId=

check this out [Google sign in failed com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47619229/google-sign-in-failed-com-google-android-gms-common-api-apiexception-10)

Comment: It worked for the first time. But after uninstalling and reinstalling the app, it threw the same exception again.

Answer (score 0):

After Uploading to **play store**, Play store generate its own `SHA1` which we have to replace in second key in google console and Make sure you add your `SHA1` to the **firebase** project.

Go to google console>app signing> copy SH1 generate by console. Add that in google sign in console **replace** it from 2nd `key`.

[image]

look at this if it help you: [Google sign in failed com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47619229/google-sign-in-failed-com-google-android-gms-common-api-apiexception-10)

Comment: SHA-1 and SHA-256 are same in Firebase and Play Store Console

Comment: Save failed
The package name and fingerprint pair you provided is already used by an Android OAuth 2.0 client ID in this project or another project

It gave me this error

Comment: delete your OAuth and add new one.

Comment: I've added the Play Store's SHA-1 certificate fingerprint (App signing key certificate
) to GCP APIs and Services and Firebase SDK setup and configuration. But it's still not working.

Comment: look at this : https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/oauth/cloud-project