# Google Login Not Working for Android with ApiException 10

Tags: android, google-signin

We try to add google login to our android app but keep getting this exception:

com.google.android.gms.tasks.RuntimeExecutionException: com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10:

[Exception Stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMEV0.jpg)

[How SHA-1 is created][2]

Here is the instruction we followed: https://developers.google.cn/identity/sign-in/android/start

Used Android Studio -> Tasks-> SignReport to create SHA-1
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSPPS.png

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47620437/11629088) may help you

Answer (score 0):

Update: Reconnecting firebase fixed the issue.