# Signin button is not directing to home page after sign in with google

Tags: flutter

I created a `SignInbutton` in my login page for the "Sign in With Google" option, I connected it with firebase and everything is working properly but after I signed in with my Google mail-id the app is not directing to the home page and the mail-id is not getting added to the firebase authentication. I am getting a error like this:

> [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception:
> PlatformException(sign_in_failed,
> com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null, null)
> E/flutter (30143): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope
> (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:597:7) E/flutter
> (30143): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod
> (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:158:18) E/flutter
> (30143):  E/flutter (30143): #2
> MethodChannel.invokeMapMethod
> (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:358:43) E/flutter
> (30143):  E/flutter (30143): #3
> GoogleSignIn._callMethod
> (package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart:235:30) E/flutter (30143):
>  E/flutter (30143): #4
> GoogleSignIn.signIn.isCanceled
> (package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart) E/flutter (30143):

this is the code i wrote

```
children: [
                    GestureDetector(
                      child: SignInButton(
                        Buttons.Google,
                        onPressed: () {
                          AuthClass()
                              .signWithGoogle()
                              .then((UserCredential value) {
                            final displayName = value.user!.displayName;

                            print(displayName);

                            Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) => HomePage()),
                                    (route) => false);
                          });
                        },
                        text: 'Sign In with Google',
                      ),
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47619229/8244668 Check this. It's the SHA-1 issue.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple possibilities as to what may be the cause.

1. Check that google-sign-in is enabled on firebase authentication.
2. Make sure that you have registered your `SHA-1` fingerprint.
3. Download the configurations depending on the platform you are using. `google-services.json` should be in your folder if you are using Android. `GoogleService-info.plist` is the configuration file for IOS.

Also it would be a good idea to update the **google_sign_in** plugin in your `pubspec.yaml` to rule out outdated package dependencies.