# Google Sign-in throws com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform

I have an Android app in which I'm using Google Sign-in (via GoogleSignInClient).

Please note that my app does NOT use Firebase and has no Firebase configuration file or imports.

When I first set up this project, I went to Google Cloud Platform, I created a new project, I went to APIs & Services, I chose Credentials. I added a new OAuth client ID and chose "Web Application" as the application type (someone told me to do this, even though my client is an Android app). I got the client ID and put it into my app, and it worked.

Later, I needed to refactor my app and change the package name. Now Google Sign-In doesn't work anymore. It throws ApiException 10.

I don't understand how changing the package name could have broken this, since the package name was never used for generating the client ID to begin with.

Thanks,
Frank

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47619229/google-sign-in-failed-com-google-android-gms-common-api-apiexception-10