# How to use a Google Cloud Project and Different Firebase Project Together For a Flutter App

Tags: android, flutter, google-cloud-platform, firebase-analytics, google-cloud-console

### Goal

I am currently working for a company where I need to access the People API from Google Cloud (for which I have set up OAuth) and also utilize Firebase's Analytics

### Problem

I get this error:

> `google_sign_in plugin:PlatformException(sign_in_failed,com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null)`

when I try to get access to the People API via OAuth.
This happens only when I specify the dependencies for **google play services** in the `gradle` files (app and project level) [Check SDK Instructions for Firebase Android Project.].

### Things I tried

1. Giving all of the possible SHA keys for the app in the Google Cloud's credentials tab from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47619229/google-sign-in-failed-com-google-android-gms-common-api-apiexception-10/47620437#47620437:%7E:text=Here%20is%20how%20I%20made%20it%20to%20work.) answer
2. Given support email for OAuth
3. Tried getting rid of the google play services dependencies from `gradle` files, this did solve the `google_sign_in` issue but Firebase Analytics stopped working and I get this error:

> `Missing google_app_id. Firebase Analytics disabled. See shortened_link_that_I_cant_post`

### Conclusion

Right now I am stuck with using only one of the two services. I removed Firebase from my Project and my App from Firebase console for now.

### Packages Concerned

1. google_sign_in: ^5.4.3: https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in
2. extension_google_sign_in_as_googleapis_auth: ^2.0.7: https://pub.dev/packages/extension_google_sign_in_as_googleapis_auth
3. googleapis: ^10.0.0: https://pub.dev/packages/googleapis
4. firebase_core and firebase_analytics

Comment: Have you tried to "Safelist Client ID's from External Project" under Firebase->Authentiication->Sign-In Method->Google? There is also the option to migrate users from the other project into your new one: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/import-users

Comment: @sleepystar96 Hey, thanks for your comment.
Do I need to do this even if I am not authenticating from Firebase? I am not using Firebase for user-related tasks, only for basic analytics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` inside `android/app/build.gradle` you comment this and it may solve the problem for you. I don't know if it will have a big effect on Firebase, but this solves the problem.

You can read the docs `https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects` and search `Deleting apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' from your app build.gradle`

Update 1: I found if you add at first or replace in `oauth_client` inside `google-services.json` at client_id where client_type=3 with web platform Google cloud credentials oauth client id, you can keep `apply plugin: 'com .google.gms.google-services'`, google services code will generate google service values.xml with `default_web_client_id` attribute as your web client id, then this solves the problem.

Update 2: After reading google_sign_in carefully.

- I found that you can set serverClientId according to web platform Google cloud credentials oauth client id and google_sign_in will not get `default_web_client_id` in file `google-services` `values. xml`. this solves the problem without changing `google-services.json` or comment`apply: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`
- Or you can remove `client_id` where `client_type` = 3 in `oauth_client` in `google-services.json` and not have to set `serverClientId`

**Update 24/05/2023**: if you need read `idToken` when sign_in. You should to do `Update 1`

Comment: Thanks, I am not longer working on the project but by far your answer seems very helpful in understanding why I was messing up.