# Unable to login using Google Plus, getting com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10:

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to login with Google plus using Firebase and getting below error:

```
com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10:
```

I refereed https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin

Here is my code below:

```
package com.example.stackoverflow;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 111;
GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            signIn();
        }
    });

    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .build();
    mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);
}

private void signIn() {
    Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        // The Task returned from this call is always completed, no need to attach
        // a listener.
        Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
        handleSignInResult(task);
    }
}

private void handleSignInResult(Task<GoogleSignInAccount> completedTask) {
    try {
        GoogleSignInAccount account = completedTask.getResult(ApiException.class);
        String name = account.getDisplayName();
        String email = account.getEmail();
        Toast.makeText(this, "name: "+name+", email: "+email, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d("NIKHIL","name: "+name+", email: "+email);
        // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
        //updateUI(account);
    } catch (ApiException e) {
        // The ApiException status code indicates the detailed failure reason.
        // Please refer to the GoogleSignInStatusCodes class reference for more information.
        Log.w("NIKHIL", "signInResult:failed code=" + e.getStatusCode());
        //updateUI(null);
    }
}
}
```

Here is my app.gradle below:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.stackoverflow"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.0.3'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.8.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I have also imported valid `google-services.json` file from Firebase. But don't understand where I am going wrong.

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47437678/why-do-i-get-com-google-android-gms-common-api-apiexception-10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The status code which you got error means that you are providing unknown server client id. 
Please checked your id  using below link. https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials 
in your project you might need to generate: 
OAuth client ID -> Web Application and use this web application client id in your Android app.

Hope it helps you and solved your problem.If your problem solved using this then please closed your question with upvote.