# Unable to Login With Google Android getting API Exception 10

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I have been trying to integrate Firebase Google Login in my app but I am getting                                                               **com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10:**

Based on this [Stack Overflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48090154/unable-to-login-using-google-plus-getting-com-google-android-gms-common-api-api?noredirect=1&lq=1), I have even tried using WebClient Client ID but still getting the same error!

Based on this [Stack Overflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47619229/google-sign-in-failed-com-google-android-gms-common-api-apiexception-10), I have entered my Debug KeyStore SHA1, SHA256 and enabled Google Login

On Android Side, I have followed this [Github Project](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/auth/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/auth/GoogleSignInActivity.java)

[image: I have added SHA 1 and SHA256 of my debug keystore]

I even tried with this Client ID but still getting the same error!
Where am I going wrong? 
[image: I even tried with this CLient ID but still getting same error!]

Comment: I have the same problem building from ubuntu 16.04 with android studio.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After struggling for two day I finally got the solution.
You need to add the SHA from your Google Play Console Dashboard.
Go to **Release Management->App Signing**
Add this SHA in firebase console.

This works only in release apk version

Update: This is because I enabled Google Play App Signing while uploading the app for the first time.
[image]

Comment: Thanks! Remember that this only works for APK that use Google Play App Signing (as mentioned on top of your screenshot).

Comment: which SHA-1 should i use? APP SIGNING or UPLOAD CERTIFICATe

Comment: @ShikharJaiswal App Signing SHA-1

Comment: @DhruvKaushal do I have to download the google services.json again and overwrite the existing?

Answer (score 3):

In the google-services.json there are two clients types (at least in my case) my error was that I was copying the wrong web_id from client_id type 1 and below there's another client_id which type is 3 and that's the correct one!!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that the string from: R.string.default_web_client_id is the Web API Key from Firebase > Project Settings.

Comment: I don't think there's anything to "make sure". That value is auto generated from the google-services.json, which is generated on firebase.

Answer (score 0):

For other folks who get here, and don't use Google Play Signing, the solution is to do the following within Android Studio:

-TOOLS->FIREBASE (Assistant with Firebase Context will open).
-Click and drop down "Authentication"
-Click "Email and Password Authentication" -OR- "CONNECT TO FIREBASE"
-Dialog with "Existing Connection Found" with SYNC Button appears
-Click "SYNC" and then build and all should be good again