# Android - Firebase Auth Not Working After PC Format

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I'm using Firebase Authentication in my Android app. Recently, I have formatted my PC and installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (It has Ubuntu 16 installed before the format), and after I installed Android Studio and tried the app, the Google sign in was not working, there is an `ApiException` thrown on those two lines:

```
GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
            firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
```

The stack trace:

```
com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: 
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.ApiExceptionUtil.fromStatus(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(Unknown Source)
        at com.game.ameer.ta7adialma3rifa.fragments.login.LoginFragment.onActivityResult(LoginFragment.java:220)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onActivityResult(FragmentActivity.java:151)
        at com.game.ameer.ta7adialma3rifa.activities.LoginActivity.onActivityResult(LoginActivity.java:38)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7303)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4516)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4563)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap22(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1698)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1518)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)
```

This didn't happen before I format the PC, and I believe that the problem is not in the code but in Firebase configuration, with some sort of token or certificate. **What is causing the problem? And how to solve it?**

Comment: Check if you have the JSON file.

Comment: I have it, as I said, this was a fully-functioning project before the format, I have the same project files of the working version.

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47437678/why-do-i-get-com-google-android-gms-common-api-apiexception-10

Comment: Thanks, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

It's most probably because the debug SHA-1 signing-certificate added to your Firebase project has changed after the format. You may need to update the key for your app on the [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com). The same goes for the [API keys](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials) of the connected project on the [Google Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/).

To get your new SHA-1 key, use the following in any terminal (on Linux/macOS):

```
keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

See [here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth) for more details