# Google Signin working in release apk but not on play store?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-oauth, android-googleapiclient

I have this very annoyiing issue in my app. Firstly it was not working in the release apk, so I added another fingerprint in Firebase(from SHA-1 finferprint in Release Management of my app in play console), but now that it has been successfully uploaded to the play store, Iam getting the API Exception:10. while sign in. Cant tell whats going wrong

Comment: Is this helpful to you please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47437678/why-do-i-get-com-google-android-gms-common-api-apiexception-10/47480986

Comment: It is probably because Google changes your key when uploading. In your Google Developer Console you can find your new SHA key under App Signing. Update your Firebase project accordingly.

Comment: @VrushiPatel, thnx  but unfortunately it didnt help much :|

Comment: @El_Loco, you're a life saver! you are the best :)))

Comment: add your SHA-1 debug key version [here](http://console.developers.google.com/apis)

Comment: under **credentials** of **OAuth Client ID**