# My Android App is allowing first time google sign in and after that it is providing below error ApiException: 10:

Tags: android

So My app work flow is like this

1. whenever a New user/ Old user comes, they login / register through google sign in option
2. I take name and email id details from user google data post their sign in
3. And then I take user entried Data ( my requirement) along with his name and send it to google sheets ( using it as database)

Now the point is at point no. 1 whenever I am trying to do it in development mode, It runs with my google sign in. However whenever I publish it with a signed in bundle APK to share it among my peers for a QA, it is failing with APi exception 10 as given below.

Can someone help me this. It is the only thing stopping me with publishing this app

````
2020-12-06 11:19:58.855 32100-32100/com.example.a100daysofpushup W/Choreographer: Already have a pending vsync event.  There should only be one at a time.
2020-12-06 11:19:58.860 32100-32100/com.example.a100daysofpushup D/OnePlusJankManager:  Chor uploadMDM JANK_TYPE_ONCE mViewTitle = com.example.a100daysofpushup/com.example.a100daysofpushup.defaultSignIn--- jank level = 1
2020-12-06 11:19:58.865 32100-32100/com.example.a100daysofpushup D/OnePlusJankManager:  Chor uploadMDM JANK_TYPE_ONCE mViewTitle = com.example.a100daysofpushup/com.example.a100daysofpushup.defaultSignIn--- jank level = 1
2020-12-06 11:19:59.684 32100-32100/com.example.a100daysofpushup W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@e368c42
2020-12-06 11:19:59.763 32100-32100/com.example.a100daysofpushup V/ViewRootImpl: The specified message queue synchronization  barrier token has not been posted or has already been removed
2020-12-06 11:19:59.790 32100-32123/com.example.a100daysofpushup D/DecorView: onWindowFocusChangedFromViewRoot hasFocus: true, DecorView@577533e[SignInHubActivity]
2020-12-06 11:19:59.807 32100-32100/com.example.a100daysofpushup W/Choreographer: Already have a pending vsync event.  There should only be one at a time.
2020-12-06 11:20:02.128 32100-32100/com.example.a100daysofpushup D/signInRes:failed code=: com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: 
2020-12-06 11:20:02.132 32100-32123/com.example.a100daysofpushup D/DecorView: onWindowFocusChangedFromViewRoot hasFocus: true, DecorView@c8b8dde[defaultSignIn]```
````

Comment: Did you see this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47437678/why-do-i-get-com-google-android-gms-common-api-apiexception-10

Comment: i saw that and I m using that SHA1 key in my gradle file only. Still it isnt working

Comment: Hammered this as a dupe of the canonical debugging question because it lacks an MCVE and it lacks the exact error, and it's a waste of votes to go for the debug reason. I'd close as a dupe of the question Henry linked, but I'm not familiar enough with Firebase to tell whether it applies here or not. Creating a [mcve] is not optional.

Answer (score -1):

For released APK you need to provide the release SHA1 to your console.

You can generate your release SHA1 key this command:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore C:\Users\SB\Desktop\myApp.jks -alias myApp
```

> On windows,  Go to your installed JDK Directory e.g. \Java\jdk1.8.0_231\bin, open the command line and try the above commands for generating SHA1.

After generating release SHA1, replace it with your already provided SHA1 in console. (If you are using Firebase you will need to update your **google-service.json** file too.