# Google OAuth2 returning either error 10 or error 12500 when signing in from Android

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services, google-signin

I am experiencing these two errors differently.

Recently I had time to do some improvements for my Android project. Until last years changes to Scopes by Google, all worked just fine. I was and still am using googles code snipp for Sign-in. The Sign-In dialog popups up with choice of my Google Accounts.

I was receiving `com.google.android.gms.common.api.b: 12500`, if I did not have the Android OAuth Credential in Google Console created (as suggested by [Google Sign In error 12500](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47632035/google-sign-in-error-12500)). After fixing that by adding all OAuth2 Credentials via using Firebase Integration -> Sign-in -> Google,

I am receiving `com.google.android.gms.common.api.b: 10` currently. To attempt to fix the issue, I have:

- Several times re-created all Credentials in Google Cloud Console
- Tried using older google gradle plugin for com.google.android.gms.auth (18.1)
- Configured ONLY App signing SHA-1 in Firebase and OAuth2 Credential for Release (into linked Google Cloud Console project, via Firebase Google Sign-In integration) and Debug (manually, in other Google Cloud Console project) builds as per fix for `12500` and `10` errors
- Linked Firebase apps to corresponding Google Play Store apps
- Added all information in `OAuth consent screen` tab in Google Cloud Console
- Added valid support email in Firebase (as suggested in [Google sign in failed com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47619229/google-sign-in-failed-com-google-android-gms-common-api-apiexception-10))
- Added up-to-date `google-services.json` to all flavors and variants of my App in the source and rebuilt project, based on Gradle's `signinReport` data
- Verified that Package name is in correct format and name

Still, I got error 10.

When not even the Google Sign-In window is show with email choice, this is spawned in Logs:

````
2021-03-21 11:59:36.109 1726-3785/? E/DollieAdapterService: notifyActivityState pkg:com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.ui.SignInActivity state:2 fg:true mUid:10019
2021-03-21 11:59:36.195 1726-3785/? E/DollieAdapterService: notifyActivityState pkg:<package_name>/com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInHubActivity state:2 fg:true mUid:10227
2021-03-21 11:59:36.265 1726-3785/? E/DollieAdapterService: notifyActivityState pkg:com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.ui.SignInActivity state:4 fg:false mUid:10019
2021-03-21 11:59:36.421 1270-1440/? E/WindowManager: win=Window{618de97 u0 <package_name>/com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInHubActivity EXITING} destroySurfaces: appStopped=false win.mWindowRemovalAllowed=true win.mRemoveOnExit=true```
````

Answer (score 1):

might be a little late, but I was experiencing something similar.
In my case, the .aab bundle file in the play store was somehow signed with a different key than the release .apk.

I was able to find it out by downloading the apk from the play store account and then using the keytool to extract the SHA1 key. Works with .aab too

I am not exactly sure why it was like this, but I have added that key in the API console and now everything works!

Comment: Thanks! Since some time, there is an Verify button in OAUTH2 screen in Google Cloud Console. I am now testing if this verification also means that this issue is solved.

Answer (score 0):

One of following helped:

- Complete rebuild and re-installation of app in test devices using ADB Plugin since Android Studio usually fails to do proper and clean re(install)
- Complete overhaul of OAuth2 IDs in multiple Google Cloud projects

UPDATE - 2023:

Again same issue has hit me. Currently the following excerpts are being tested

in https://stackoverflow.com/a/63777860/132296 , the need to have an OAUTH2 "Android client" created in Google Cloud Console for each and every App is mentioned together with "Web client" ; if this is not done, the 12500 error is shown

in https://stackoverflow.com/a/59969445/132296 , the need to have proper value for downloaded JSON from Firebase is needed to be adjusted accordingly ; if this is not done, the 10 error is shown