# AndroidStudio Exception when starting android in a libgdx project

Tags: libgdx, android-studio-3.0

I get an exception when running the android gradle task in Android Studio 3.0.1. My project is build with libgdx. My desktop gradle task runs just perfect.

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':android:validateSigningDebug'.
```

where the root cause is

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: class "org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.symmetric.IDEA$Mappings"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package
```

I have absoluty no idea how to fix this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java SecurityException: signer information does not match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2877262/java-securityexception-signer-information-does-not-match) Specifically this answer "In my case, I had duplicated JAR version of BouncyCastle in my library path". Double check your library path, and if that's not the case, then see the other answers to that question.

Comment: Solution for me was to create a debug key store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mar Dev gave the right hint for me. I did:

```
cd ~/.android
keytool -genkey -v -keystore debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore debug.keystore -destkeystore debug.keystore -deststoretype pkcs12
```

Then in AndroidStudio I followed the accepted answer of [Where is debug.keystore in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16965058/where-is-debug-keystore-in-android-studio)