# my app is showing blank map

Tags: android, google-maps, google-cloud-platform, google-maps-android-api-2

I am using google map api in my app.The map was working perfectly but now it get blanked.Map is still working but not loading the map.I was searching answer for hours but didn't get any results.I have created a new api at google cloud platform and put that api but still not loading the map.
Anyone who can help me with this. Thanks!

Here is the screenshot of blank map. 
[Screenshot of map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKqqS.png)

```
07-21 21:28:59.573 18146-18265/com.example.har.firebaseauthenticationdemo E/Google Maps Android API: Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start for how to correctly set up the map.
07-21 21:28:59.575 18146-18265/com.example.har.firebaseauthenticationdemo E/Google Maps Android API: In the Google Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com)
                                                                                                     Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
                                                                                                     Ensure that the following Android Key exists:
                                                                                                        API Key: AIzaSyDWCP4m0DF57jZU4V8Yr7RFP2-DmhpgL34
                                                                                                        Android Application (<cert_fingerprint>;<package_name>): 0E:0E:68:77:05:BB:76:A3:5C:BC:62:F8:6A:AB:A5:5F:2A:7F:37:5F;com.example.har.firebaseauthenticationdemo
07-21 21:29:00.571 2256-2451/? E/Auth: [GoogleAccountDataServiceImpl] getToken() -> BAD_AUTHENTICATION. Account: <ELLIDED:-895295850>, App: com.google.android.gms, Service: oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/login_manager
                                       fkq: Long live credential not available.
                                           at fkr.b(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):20)
                                           at fkr.a(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):50)
                                           at fjb.a(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):35)
                                           at gzf.a(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):8)
                                           at gzf.a(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):160)
                                           at gyf.a(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):2)
                                           at gyc.a(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):17)
                                           at gyc.a(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):6)
                                           at cug.a(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):25)
                                           at cug.a(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):79)
                                           at cug.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):8)
                                           at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:627)
                                           at cwl.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):3)
                                           at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:697)
07-21 21:29:00.611 2256-3646/? E/Auth: [GoogleAccountDataServiceImpl] getToken() -> BAD_AUTHENTICATION. Account: <ELLIDED:-895295850>, App: com.google.android.gms, Service: oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/login_manager
                                       fkq: Long live credential not available.
                                           at fkr.b(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):20)
                                           at fkr.a(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):50)
                                           at fjb.a(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):35)
                                           at gzf.a(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):8)
                                           at gzf.a(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):160)
                                           at gyf.a(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):2)
                                           at gyc.a(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):17)
                                           at gyc.a(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):6)
                                           at cug.a(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):25)
                                           at cug.a(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):79)
                                           at cug.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):8)
                                           at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:627)
                                           at cwl.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):3)
                                           at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:697)
07-21 21:29:00.673 2256-3646/? E/Auth: [GoogleAccountDataServiceImpl] getToken() -> BAD_AUTHENTICATION. Account: <ELLIDED:-895295850>, App: com.google.android.gms, Service: oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/login_manager
                                       fkq: Long live credential not available.
                                           at fkr.b(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):20)
                                           at fkr.a(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):50)
                                           at fjb.a(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):35)
                                           at gzf.a(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):8)
                                           at gzf.a(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):160)
                                           at gyf.a(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):2)
                                           at gyc.a(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):17)
                                           at gyc.a(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):6)
                                           at cug.a(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):25)
                                           at cug.a(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):79)
                                           at cug.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):8)
                                           at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:627)
                                           at cwl.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):3)
                                           at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:697)
07-21 21:29:00.748 2426-18282/? E/ChromeSync: [Sync,SyncAdapter] Failed to sync.
                                              mbz: fgj: BadAuthentication
                                                  at mfy.a(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):5)
                                                  at mgm.a(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):42)
                                                  at mgn.a(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):22)
                                                  at mgn.a(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):73)
                                                  at mgn.b(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):7)
                                                  at mgl.a(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):41)
                                                  at nrg.onPerformSync(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):5)
                                                  at android.content.AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter$SyncThread.run(AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter.java:321)
                                               Caused by: fgj: BadAuthentication
                                                  at ffx.a(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):13)
                                                  at ffw.a(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):2)
                                                  at ffw.e(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):6)
                                                  at ffw.d(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):1)
                                                  at ffu.b(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):1)
                                                  at nms.b(Unknown Source:6)
                                                  at nlf.b(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):5)
                                                  at nlw.a(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):58)
                                                  at mfy.a(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):1)
                                                  at mgm.a(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):42) 
                                                  at mgn.a(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):22) 
                                                  at mgn.a(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):73) 
                                                  at mgn.b(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):7) 
                                                  at mgl.a(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):41) 
                                                  at nrg.onPerformSync(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):5) 
                                                  at android.content.AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter$SyncThread.run(AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter.java:321) 
07-21 21:29:03.389 1599-1612/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
07-21 21:29:05.559 1599-1612/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
07-21 21:29:05.574 1599-1612/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
07-21 21:29:12.866 2256-18310/? E/Auth: [GoogleAccountDataServiceImpl] getToken() -> BAD_AUTHENTICATION. Account: <ELLIDED:-895295850>, App: com.google.android.gms, Service: oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/experimentsandconfigs
                                        fkq: Long live credential not available.
                                            at fkr.b(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):20)
                                            at fkr.a(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):50)
                                            at fjb.a(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):35)
                                            at gzf.a(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):8)
                                            at gzf.a(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):160)
                                            at gyf.a(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):2)
                                            at gyc.a(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):17)
                                            at gyc.a(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):6)
                                            at cug.a(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):25)
                                            at cug.a(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):79)
                                            at ffx.a(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):6)
                                            at ffw.a(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):2)
                                            at ffw.e(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):6)
                                            at ffu.f(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):3)
                                            at ffu.a(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):4)
                                            at ffu.a(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):7)
                                            at aenk.a(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):22)
                                            at aenm.a(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):130)
                                            at aenm.a(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):243)
                                            at aenm.a(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):404)
                                            at com.google.android.gms.phenotype.sync.HeterodyneSyncTaskChimeraService.a(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):66)
                                            at com.google.android.gms.phenotype.sync.HeterodyneSyncTaskChimeraService.a(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):20)
                                            at ulu.run(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):1)
                                            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
                                            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
                                            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
07-21 21:29:12.884 2256-18310/? E/HeterodyneSyncTaskChime: Failed to get auth token: User intervention required. Notification has been pushed. -- metadata{ service_id: 51 }
                                                           fgk: User intervention required. Notification has been pushed.
                                                               at ffu.f(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):10)
                                                               at ffu.a(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):4)
                                                               at ffu.a(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):7)
                                                               at aenk.a(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):22)
                                                               at aenm.a(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):130)
                                                               at aenm.a(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):243)
                                                               at aenm.a(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):404)
                                                               at com.google.android.gms.phenotype.sync.HeterodyneSyncTaskChimeraService.a(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):66)
                                                               at com.google.android.gms.phenotype.sync.HeterodyneSyncTaskChimeraService.a(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):20)
                                                               at ulu.run(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):1)
                                                               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
                                                               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
                                                               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Comment: Do you setup google console settings, like enable map API & adding Api key?

Comment: yes i have setup google console and map was working completely fine. this problem came 2 days ago.

Comment: Please update your question with  logcat after opening map and  that will help for addressing this issue.

Comment: Please check my answer, You need to validate google console setup.

Comment: you got issues with the google map api..make sure is enabled n use that key in your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.

- Go to [Google Console](https://console.developers.google.com/apis) APIs and search for Maps for android API. and ensure it's enabled.

> Ensure that the following Android Key exists:

- Go to Google Console Credential Manager. and add android API key for debug and release. Check [Google Doc](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/signup) for more details.

**Update 1**

- From your logcat.

> 07-21 21:28:59.573
>   18146-18265/com.example.har.firebaseauthenticationdemo E/Google Maps
>   Android API: Authorization failure.

**Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start for how to correctly set up the map.**

**Update 2**

**build.gradle**

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            resValue "string", "google_maps_api_key", "Release_API_KEY"
        }
        debug {
//          KL MBP debug Key
            resValue "string", "google_maps_api_key", "DEBUG_API_KEY"
//          KL Old Machine debug Key
//            resValue "string", "google_maps_api_key", "DEBUG_API_KEY"
        }
    }
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_api_key"/>

    <uses-library
        android:name="com.google.android.maps"
        android:required="true" />
```

**Update 3**

**Get SHA1 to be used on generate API KEY**

- For Linux or macOS, open a terminal window and enter the following:

> macOS and Linux: `~/.android/`

```
 keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

- For Windows Vista and Windows 7, run:

> Windows Vista and Windows 7:

`C:\Users\your_user_name\.android\ List the SHA-1 fingerprint:`

```
keytool -list -v -keystore "%USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

**Update 4**

In Android Studio you can find all your app signing information without any console command:

1. Open your project
2. Click on Gradle from right side panel
3. In Gradle projects panel open folders: Your Project -> Tasks-> Android
4. Run signingReport task (double click) and you will see the result in Gradle console (keystore paths,SHA1,MD5 and so on).

Comment: i don't have "Google Maps Android API v2" in the list of Api's

Comment: Yellow quote from your logcat.

Comment: can we use the same api key for debug and release?

Comment: No, But you can specify both of them on `build.gradle` check my **update 2**

Comment: i did all these changes but still i am getting the blank map.

Comment: Did you create a project on [Google console](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/dashboard) and enabled `Maps for android API`?

Comment: yes i created project and enabled maps for android.

Comment: Did you added **API key** On the [Credentials page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/signup)?, Consider this may take a while to take effect.

Comment: yes i added api key on credentials page. then i added the same api key to my debug and release tag in gradle file.

Comment: Please scroll throw this link and read paragraph with this title [Detailed guides to getting an API key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/signup),

Comment: Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43858904/1283715) to get `SHA1` then use on generate `API key` .

Comment: by following your updates. my map is finally working. i have created new api and add restriction on it following update 4. this solve my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make new app.A week ago i made a webview app after 2 days webview is not load anything umntil make new one.

Comment: i am doing so many things using map i have to setup all these things too. any other solution rather then that?

Answer (score 0):

1.Get Google Maps API Key

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/signup?authuser=1

2.Place this API key either in strings.xml or Android Manifest

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
    android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
```

**string.xml**

```
<string name="google_maps_key">YOUR_API_KEY</string>
```

3.Put `SupportMapFragment` inside Your desirable xml

```
<fragment
   android:id="@+id/placesMap"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
   android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
   android:tag="@string/tag_places_search_map"
   class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

and finally the `Activity` class

```
class SampleActivity :
        GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener,
        GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener,
        GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener,
        GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowLongClickListener,
        GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowCloseListener,
        OnMapAndViewReadyListener.OnGlobalLayoutAndMapReadyListener,
        GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback
{
    private lateinit var map: GoogleMap

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val mapFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.placesMap) as SupportMapFragment
        OnMapAndViewReadyListener(mapFragment, this)
    }

    internal inner class CustomInfoWindowAdapter : GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter {

        // These are both view groups containing an ImageView with id "badge" and two
        // TextViews with id "title" and "snippet".
        private val window: View = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_info_window, null)
        private val contents: View = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_info_contents, null)

        override fun getInfoWindow(marker: Marker): View? {
             render(marker, window)
            return window
        }

        override fun getInfoContents(marker: Marker): View? {
            render(marker, contents)
            return contents
        }

        private fun render(marker: Marker, view: View) {

            // Set the title and snippet for the custom info window
            val title: String? = marker.title
            val titleUi = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.title)

            if (title != null) {
                // Spannable string allows us to edit the formatting of the text.
                titleUi.text = SpannableString(title).apply {
                    setSpan(ForegroundColorSpan(resources.getColor(R.color.text_grey_heading)), 0, length, 0)
                }
            } else {
                titleUi.text = ""
            }

            val snippet: String? = marker.snippet
            val snippetUi = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.snippet)
            snippetUi.text = snippet
        }
    }

    override fun onMarkerClick(marker: Marker?): Boolean {
        marker?.zIndex = marker?.zIndex?.plus(1.0f)!!
        val handler = Handler()
        val start = SystemClock.uptimeMillis()
        val duration = 1500

        val interpolator = BounceInterpolator()

        handler.post(object : Runnable {
            override fun run() {
                val elapsed = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - start
                val t = Math.max(
                        1 - interpolator.getInterpolation(elapsed.toFloat() / duration), 0f)
                marker?.setAnchor(0.5f, 1.0f + 2 * t)

                // Post again 16ms later.
                if (t > 0.0) {
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 16)
                }
            }
        })
        return false
    }

    override fun onMarkerDragEnd(p0: Marker?) {
    }

    override fun onMarkerDragStart(p0: Marker?) {
    }

    override fun onMarkerDrag(p0: Marker?) {
    }

    override fun onInfoWindowClick(marker : Marker) {
        //Toast.makeText(this, "Click Info Window", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

    override fun onInfoWindowClose(marker : Marker) {
        //Toast.makeText(this, "Close Info Window", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

    override fun onInfoWindowLongClick(marker : Marker) {
        //Toast.makeText(this, "Info Window long click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

    override fun onMapLoaded() {
        addMarkersToMap()
    }

    override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap?) {
        map = googleMap ?: return

        with(map) {
            // Hide the zoom controls as the button panel will cover it.
            uiSettings.isZoomControlsEnabled = false

            // Setting an info window adapter allows us to change the both the contents and
            // look of the info window.
            setInfoWindowAdapter(CustomInfoWindowAdapter())

            // Set listeners for marker events.  See the bottom of this class for their behavior.
            setOnMarkerClickListener(this@SampleActivity)
            setOnInfoWindowClickListener(this@SampleActivity)
            setOnMarkerDragListener(this@SampleActivity)
            setOnInfoWindowCloseListener(this@SampleActivity)
            setOnInfoWindowLongClickListener(this@SampleActivity)
            setOnMapLoadedCallback(this@SampleActivity)

            // Override the default content description on the view, for accessibility mode.
            // Ideally this string would be localised.
            setContentDescription("Map with lots of markers.")
        }
    }

    fun addMarkersToMap(data: List<Places>) {
        // create bounds that encompass every location we reference
        val boundsBuilder = LatLngBounds.Builder()

        data.map { place -> boundsBuilder.include(LatLng(place.venue.location.lat!!,place.venue.location.lng)) }
        val bounds = boundsBuilder.build()
        with(map){
            moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 50))
        }
        val list : MutableList<PlaceDetails> = mutableListOf<PlaceDetails>()
        for (place in data){
            list.add(PlaceDetails(place.id,LatLng(place.venue.location.lat!!,place.venue.location.lng),
                    place.venue.name,
                    place.getDistance()))
        }

        //add Seattle center as marker on map
        var seattlePD : PlaceDetails = PlaceDetails(TConstants.SEATTLLE_ID,
            LatLng(resources.getString(R.string.seattle_lat).toDouble(), resources.getString(R.string.seattle_long).toDouble()),
                "Seattle","Seattle Center",
                BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_CYAN))
        map.addMarker(MarkerOptions()
                .position(seattlePD.position)
                .title(seattlePD.title)
                .snippet(seattlePD.snippet)
                .icon(seattlePD.icon)
                .infoWindowAnchor(seattlePD.infoWindowAnchorX, seattlePD.infoWindowAnchorY)
                .draggable(seattlePD.draggable)
                .zIndex(seattlePD.zIndex))

        for (placeDetails in list){
            var marker = map.addMarker(MarkerOptions()
                    .position(placeDetails.position)
                    .title(placeDetails.title)
                    .snippet("Distance : "+placeDetails.snippet)
                    .icon(placeDetails.icon)
                    .infoWindowAnchor(placeDetails.infoWindowAnchorX, placeDetails.infoWindowAnchorY)
                    .draggable(placeDetails.draggable)
                    .zIndex(placeDetails.zIndex))
            searchViewModel.markerTracker.put(marker.id,placeDetails)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i am doing all these things and my map was working fine. the issue is map is not loading now. it become blank

Comment: **DON'T** forget to restrict your API key for security reason.