# Not showing google api version v2

Tags: android, google-maps

After running my project, it shows blank maps, I followed many methods but still shows blank now i am confused with the map api v2,my console does not shows all api version
[this is my console image it does not shows all api version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySkMn.png)

This is my java file

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;
LocationManager locationManager;
LocationListener locationListener;

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if(requestCode==1)
    {
        if(grantResults.length>0 && grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MapsActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
            }
        }
    }

}



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}


/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    locationManager=(LocationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationListener=new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            LatLng myplace = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(myplace).title("veraval").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.
                    defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(myplace,20));

        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

        }
    };


        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MapsActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this,"hello",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);

        }



}
```

This is my build.gradle file, I have added all the dependencies still it shows the blank map

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.user.mapexample"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        resValue "string", "google_maps_api_key", "Release_API_KEY"

    }
    debug{
        resValue "string", "google_maps_api_key", "DEBUG_API_KEY"
    } 
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
```

This is my logcat

```
07-26 12:14:12.046 7855-7855/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
07-26 12:14:12.071 7855-7862/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
07-26 12:14:12.071 7855-7862/? I/art: Starting a blocking GC Instrumentation
07-26 12:14:12.204 7855-7855/? D/LenovoAppIconTheme: 
ExtraResources;cleanCachedIcon;clear cache..
07-26 12:14:12.210 7855-7855/? W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: 
/data/app/com.example.user.mapsexample-1/lib/arm
07-26 12:14:12.338 7855-7855/? I/zzbz: Making Creator dynamically
07-26 12:14:12.380 7855-7855/? I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module 
com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite:0 and remote module 
com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite:220
07-26 12:14:12.380 7855-7855/? I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of 
com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite, version >= 220
07-26 12:14:12.404 7855-7855/? W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: 
07-26 12:14:12.518 7855-7855/? I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play 
services client version: 12451000
07-26 12:14:12.540 7855-7855/? I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play 
services package version: 12874022
07-26 12:14:13.312 7855-7855/com.example.user.mapsexample E/art: The 
String#value field is not present on Android versions >= 6.0
07-26 12:14:13.690 7855-7901/com.example.user.mapsexample 
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform 
default
07-26 12:14:13.709 7855-7901/com.example.user.mapsexample I/DpmTcmClient: 
RegisterTcmMonitor from: com.android.okhttp.TcmIdleTimerMonitor
07-26 12:14:13.930 7855-7936/com.example.user.mapsexample I/Adreno: QUALCOMM 
build                   : 5817cca, Ie9c95840c4
                                                                Build Date                       
: 03/26/17
                                                                OpenGL ES 
Shader Compiler Version: XE031.09.00.03
                                                                Local Branch                     
: 
                                                                Remote Branch                    
: refs/tags/AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.UM.5.5.R1.07.00.00.269.021
                                                                Remote Branch                    
: NONE
                                                                Reconstruct 
Branch               : NOTHING
07-26 12:14:13.956 7855-7936/com.example.user.mapsexample I/OpenGLRenderer: 
Initialized EGL, version 1.4
07-26 12:14:13.957 7855-7936/com.example.user.mapsexample D/OpenGLRenderer: 
Swap behavior 1
07-26 12:14:14.258 7855-7866/com.example.user.mapsexample W/art: Suspending 
all 
threads took: 18.013ms
07-26 12:14:14.287 7855-7866/com.example.user.mapsexample I/art: Background 
sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 7913(862KB) AllocSpace objects, 
20(1612KB) LOS objects, 0% free, 13MB/13MB, paused 20.215ms total 77.392ms
07-26 12:14:14.743 7855-7866/com.example.user.mapsexample I/art: Background 
sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 4729(195KB) AllocSpace objects, 4(2MB) 
LOS objects, 9% free, 25MB/28MB, paused 5.557ms total 19.833ms
07-26 12:14:16.187 7855-7934/com.example.user.mapsexample W/DynamiteModule: 
Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates 
not found.
07-26 12:14:16.199 7855-7934/com.example.user.mapsexample I/DynamiteModule: 
Considering local module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:0 and 
remote module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:4
07-26 12:14:16.199 7855-7934/com.example.user.mapsexample I/DynamiteModule: 
Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates, version 
>= 4
```

[image: This is the output I am getting in my physical device]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start for how to correctly set up the map.
- **Ensure API KEY exists in your app**:

  - Go to Google Console Credential Manager. and add android API key for debug and release. Check [Google Doc](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/signup) for more details.

**build.gradle**

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            resValue "string", "google_maps_api_key", "Release_API_KEY"
        }
        debug {
//          KL MBP debug Key
            resValue "string", "google_maps_api_key", "DEBUG_API_KEY"
//          KL Old Machine debug Key
//            resValue "string", "google_maps_api_key", "DEBUG_API_KEY"
        }
    }
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="@string/google_maps_api_key"/>

<uses-library
    android:name="com.google.android.maps"
    android:required="true" />
```

**Check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51458150/1283715) for more details on** how to setup API key `google_maps_api_key` and add to `build.gradle` as release or debug.

**Update 1**

- **Easy way to setup Google Maps API key.**
- To get one, follow this link, follow the directions and press "Create" at the end:

  `https://console.developers.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=maps_android_backend&keyType=CLIENT_SIDE_ANDROID&r={SHA-1}%3B{YOUR_APP_PACKAGE_NAME}`

  - Ex:

    `https://console.developers.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=maps_android_backend&keyType=CLIENT_SIDE_ANDROID&r=08:F2:4F:C5:43:3E:4E:B7:30:71:0F:06:F1:9F:85:F5:E2:1D:B8:73%3Bcom.lelasoft.googlemapv2`

> **Note**: It may take up to 5 minutes for settings to take effect

**Update 2**

- I created  new `MapActivity` and it works with me after setup API key using **Update 1** instruction and it take about 5 minutes to take effect

**Update 3**

- Set Android emulator GeoLocation

[image]

**Update 4**

- Ask user to enable `GeoLocation` on device.

**build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
     // Other dependences 
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1' // add location dependency.
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
}
```

**MapsActivity.java**

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    this.googleMap = googleMap;
    buildGoogleApiClient();
    googleApiClient.connect();
}

protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    googleMap.clear();
    LatLng myplace = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(myplace).title("Marker in My Current Location"));
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(myplace,17));
}

/**
 * Enables the My Location layer if the fine mLocation permission has been granted.
 */
private void enableMyLocation() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN
            && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION_PERMISSION);
    }else if (googleApiClient != null && locationRequest !=null){
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, locationRequest, this);
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                       @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION_PERMISSION:
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                enableMyLocation();
            }
            break;
        default:
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION_PERMISSION){
        enableMyLocation();
    }
}


@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (googleApiClient !=null)
        createLocationRequest();
}


protected void createLocationRequest() {
    locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    locationRequest.setInterval(30 * 1000);
    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5 * 1000);
    LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
            .addLocationRequest(locationRequest);
    //**************************
    builder.setAlwaysShow(true); //this is the key ingredient
    //**************************
    PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result =
            LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(googleApiClient, builder.build());
    result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(@NonNull LocationSettingsResult result) {
            final Status status = result.getStatus();
            final LocationSettingsStates state = result.getLocationSettingsStates();
            switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                    // All mLocation settings are satisfied. The client can initialize mLocation
                    // requests here.
                    enableMyLocation();
                    break;
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                    // Location settings are not satisfied. But could be fixed by showing the user
                    // a dialog.
                    try {
                        // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                        // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                        status.startResolutionForResult(MapsActivity.this, REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION_PERMISSION);
                    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                        // Ignore the error.
                    }
                    break;
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                    // Location settings are not satisfied. However, we have no way to fix the
                    // settings so we won't show the dialog.
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

**Check complete [Github Example](https://github.com/KhaledLela/GoogleMapV2Test).**

Comment: I've added , still the result is blank map

Comment: Please update your question with logcat when opening map.

Comment: Be careful that API key that you add to Google Console  take up to 5 minutes for settings to take effect.

Comment: Check my **Update**  >> Easy way to setup Google Maps API key

Comment: I ve added the api key in debug/res/values as well as release/res/values

Comment: and even unrestricted the api key

Comment: Try to create new project with `MapActivity` and follow instruction. I just create new one and map worked with me after setup API key and it take about 5 minutes to take effect, Updated my answer with map screen.

Comment: Did you follow instructions on **Update 1**, Please ensure you correctly put `your_package_name` & SHA-1 to the link.

Comment: Check my testApp on [Github](https://github.com/KhaledLela/GoogleMapV2Test)

Comment: I've followed all the instruction, checked my package name and SHA-1 key many times but the problem is still there.

Comment: @aksishere If my answer helped you to fix your issue, Don't forget to accept it.

Comment: Thank you ,I am trying too hard to solve the issue, still not solved, if it solved I'll surely mark it.

Comment: My marker is not showing on the specified position, what would be the reason

Comment: I am using physical device

Comment: This means that your `GeoLocation` is not opened on your device, Check my [Github example](https://github.com/KhaledLela/GoogleMapV2Test/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/lelasoft/googlemapv2/MapsActivity.java) to know how to ask user to enable GeoLocation on device.

Comment: Check my **Update 4**, hope that help you to fix your issue and learn how to ask user for enable GeoLocation, Have a nice day!

Comment: Bro u just rocked it thank you so much for this valuable ans, been searching this for like three days