# Google maps API key not working on all environments

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm having some issues with google maps on android. I already generated the API key and performed all the steps. I generated the apk and it works fine. I've done this on my laptop.

My project is in git, and cloned it into my desktop computer. When I generate the apk from my desktop computer, the maps don't work. If I go back to my laptop and generate the apk, it works.

All the files needed are in place. Any ideas about this behaviour?

Comment: Did you use the same [debug.keystore](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16965058/295004) on both machines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FOR NON SIGNED APK:
    Update SHA1 key in API console.
    While generating map key you were using your Laptop SHA1 key,S, if you are 
    generate Apk with your desktop ,kindly update SHA1 key which you are generate 
    from Desktop(Every system have unique sha1 key)

FOR SIGNED APK:
    You have to generate Apk with same Key store jks file