# Firebase: unknown status code: 12500 android oauth2

Tags: android, firebase, oauth-2.0

I have a problem with Android when using Firebase Authentication, the error is:

```
unknown status code: 12500 android oauth2
```

I created the SHA1 and it is added in the firebase console but I can't solve this.

```
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
MD5: 62:45:B2:85:A8:58:A3:33:C7:04:F7:20:01:1E:FF:93
SHA1: 7A:14:90:0D:B3:35:61:C9:D4:99:C0:C1:8A:A7:23:90:19:E0:31:BA
SHA-256: EA:1E:B8:DB:AA:41:9D:ED:42:A7:1D:50:75:DC:3C:78:A0:BB:52:52:08:9C:C0:61:27:A9:CC:C3:42:7B:B9:19
Valid until: viernes 7 de mayo de 2049
```

¿What could be the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Sign In error 12500](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47632035/google-sign-in-error-12500)

Comment: Please consider my answer if it helped you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try to fix your problem with two step .

**First Step**

Make sure you have provided a valid "Web Client Id" (Not Android) in the method `requestServerAuthCode`

check your SHA configuration. you may created a keystore and used it to generate SHA and provided it while generating `google-services.json` . But while debugging, application was using debug keystore.

Everything may work fine after you configure 'debug' version to use the same keystore. [Where is debug.keystore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16965058/where-is-debug-keystore-in-android-studio) in Android Studio.

**Second Step**

Simply update your Google Play Services to the latest version. If you are using Android virtual device , check the Google Play. Once the emulator is up and running, go to the Extended Controls Menu > Google Play then update.

Hope it helps. :)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, The two steps help me to resolve!

Comment: Please consider my answer as a correct one if it's helped you