# Can a debug apk be updated if the previous and the current apk are created by 2 different machines

Tags: android, debugging, apk

One developer creates 1.0 version debug apk on his machine . Another developer creates 1.1 version debug apk on his machine.
Both use the same android device to test applications.
If 1.0 version is installed. Can it be updated to 1.1 on the same device. Right now , we get error , app install failed. The logs show this error:  Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE: Package signatures do not match previously installed version; ignoring!

We tried to create both the versions on one machine and the update worked on the android device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can be updated. The machine doesn't matter. what matters is [KeyStore](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore) Copy the Keystore from the machine where version 1.0 was created and then copy it to the other machine. and that's it.

Now you can update your App.

How to find the Keystore?

Look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16965058/2299040)

Answer (score 1):

You can create the keystore for debug builds and use it to make APK files on a different machine.

1. Create new keystore `debug.keystore` with alias `android`. Both passwords for keystore and the alias should be `android`
2. In `build.gradle` for the app module (or how it is called in your project), define the signing configs, so the IDE will know how to sign debug build.
3. Use the same `debug.keystore` file on all developers' machines.

The example:

```
    android {

        signingConfigs {
            debug {
                storeFile PATH_TO_THE_DEBUG_KEYSTORE
                storePassword "android"
                keyAlias "android"
                keyPassword "android"
            }
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
```

**P.S.**
In fact, the names for `debug.keystore`, alias and passwords can be different from the suggested values. It is just simple to remember.

Comment: the android block has to be at the top level ? Can you share a build.gradle file showing this block

Comment: @kirtipriya no, `android` block is on its commonplace. `signingConfigs` should be its child