# Android Google Map has wrong cert_fingerprint

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio-3.0

I have been using google maps for a while and has not had a problem working with it.  I just upgraded to android studio 3.6.1 and when I try to get a map I get the error:

2020-03-02 15:59:58.462 32155-459/com.salinas.abuilder E/Google Maps Android API: Authorization failure.
    Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
    Ensure that the following Android Key exists:
API Key: My_API_KEY
Android Application (;): F3:CC:56:XXX:66:69:CB;com.salinas.abuilder  leaving out the middle of the value

and I cannot figure out where this cert fingerprint comes form?

Is my file google_maps_api.xml there is a cert:
26:2C:F8:XXX:0C:BB:3D leaving out the middle of the value

I have no idea where the cert that is used comes from, the one in my xml file is the one google lists for the package name.  Is there any way to resolve this or do I just have to build a new project?

Comment: I would double check your [debug/release key](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16965058/295004) to see if it is the same as configured in the Google API.

Comment: you are correct when I run the signing report it shows the SHA1 key as the wrong value?  Do I get a new key with the wrong value and make it correct or can I change the sha1 value?  I wonder how it got changed?

Comment: Thanks, I just applied new credentials to the old key and it works fine, thank you.