# How to generate a different debug sha1-key

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, keytool, android-signing

I have a sha1 Key for debug that I get from signinreports inside android studio.  Now, I have this key in multiple Firebase projects, and I would like to generate another debug key for this project.

How can I generate another debug key for an existing project and assign it to that project ?

I have tried with

```
keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

But is outputting the same debugkey as the other projects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Step 1) Go to File > Project Structure > select project > go to
>   "signing" and select your default or any keystore you want and fill
>   all the details. In case you are not able to fill the details, hit the
>   green '+' button.
>
> Step 2) VERY IMPORTANT: Goto Build Types> select your build type and
>   select your "Signing Config".

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17992232/4853835

**Another solution**: you can move (**move to a backup folder**) keys from this directory then build your project (Android studio will create new key):

- For Windows User: C:\Users\USERNAME.android\debug.keystore (Change USERNAME as your pc name)
- For Linux or Mac OS User: ~/.android/debug.keystore