# Sample Android project not working because of: Debug Certificate expired

Tags: android, linux, eclipse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Debug certificate expired” error in Eclipse Android plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194808/debug-certificate-expired-error-in-eclipse-android-plugins)

I am trying to run one of the sample projects that come with android (and I have tried many). I keep getting this error in eclipse's `Problems` window.

```
Error generating final archive: Debug Certificate expired on 10/24/12 7:27 AM com.example.android.mediafx.HelloEffects      Unknown Android Packaging Problem
```

Basically I import the project from the `samples` directory. Then I right click on the project and choose

```
Run As --> android project
```

Another symptom of the problem is that the project has a `red x` next to it, but no `red x` in any sub-directory or file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Delete `~/.android/debug.keystore` and try again. The ADT should generate new debug keystore with new certificate in it.

Comment: Awesome! Learning android is a challenge with all of these hiccups. (I have to wait 5 mins to accept your answer).