# Error in creating brand new package in android

Tags: android

So I am fairly new to Android development so I am starting out by following http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project.html to just get a foot hold. The problem is that when I create a project I already have an error so I can't even run hello world. I have tried searching for anyone with a similar problem but nothing seems to come up. Any insight to the problem would be much appreciated.

Comment: What error are you getting? It's hard to help you without knowing that.

Comment: would you mind defining the error, i already have an error means nothing

Comment: Please post your error and code.

Comment: You missing details of the error. How can anyone possibly help?

Comment: That's one of the problems I am having as the errors aren't very clear to myself as well. I just created the file and so I am not sure how it could really be giving me such errors but one of the things it is telling me is "Failed to load properties file for project 'Hello'". I also apologize for not being concise and describing my error in my initial post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using Eclipse? If so, try right-clicking out your project, going to "Android Tools", and clicking "fix project properties". It sounds like it may be missing (or just not generated in the first place), this should recreate it.

EDIT: It sounds like your project.properties file isn't the problem. Another thing you can try is deleting your debug keystore, it may have generated incorrectly. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194808/debug-certificate-expired-error-in-eclipse-android-plugins) for instructions.

Comment: Yes I am using Eclipse. I tried your suggestion and I am still getting the same error. I also tried cleaning my project and then rebuild and still no success.

Comment: Does your project have a project.properties file?

Comment: Yep. It doesn't have much in it except for a bunch of comments and target=android-16

Comment: Yes it totally worked! Thanks a bunch!