# Default keystore file does not exist?

Tags: java, android, keystore

I'm getting this error.

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin>keytool -list -v -keystore "C:\Users\Suresh\.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android

keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: C:\Users\Suresh\.android\debug.keystore

java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: C:\Users\Suresh\.android\debug.keystore

at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.doCommands(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.run(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.main(Unknown Source)

C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin>
```

[image]

Comment: Have you checked that the `debug.keystore` _actually_ exists in the path you are specifying?

Comment: debug.keystore file does not exist "C:\Users\Suresh\.android\"

Comment: Yes. I read the OP and I know exactly what it means. My question is, does the `debug.keystore` file exist in the path your specifying in the command?

Comment: In the path debgu.keystore file not created(or not existed)

Comment: So what's your question? 'keytool -list' doesn't create keystores, and there's nothing 'default' about that one, except in your mind.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You must be providing the wrong path to the `debug.keystore` file.

Follow these steps to get the correct path and complete your command:

1. In eclipse, click the Window menu -> Preferences -> *Expand* Android -> Build
2. In the right panel, look for: *Default debug keystore:*
3. Select the entire box next to the label specified in **Step 2**

And finally, use the path you just copied from Step 3 to construct your command:

For example, in my case, it would be:

> C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin>keytool -list -v -keystore
>   "C:\Users\Siddharth Lele.android\debug.keystore" -alias
>   androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android

**UPDATED:**

If you had already followed the steps mentioned above, the only other solution is to delete the `debug.keystore` and let Eclipse recreate it for you.

Step 1: Go to the path where your keystore is stored. In your case, `C:\Users\Suresh\.android\debug.keystore`

Step 2: Close and restart Eclipse.

Step 3 (Optional): *You may need to clean your project before the `debug.keystore` is created again.*

**Source:** http://www.coderanch.com/t/440920/Security/KeyTool-genkeypair-exception-Keystore-file

You can refer to this for the part about deleting your `debug.keystore` file: ["Debug certificate expired" error in Eclipse Android plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194808/debug-certificate-expired-error-in-eclipse-android-plugins/2196397#2196397)

Comment: What about android studio?

Comment: @SahilBabbar: It's still available at the same location. In Windows for example: `C:\Users\THE_USER\.android\debug.keystore`. That part hasn't changed.

Answer (score 27):

Use This for MAC users

```
keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

Comment: @HarisurRehman, how long did it take for you to finish this command?

Comment: @DevetiPutnik didn't take much long. Not more than a couple of minutes

Comment: Interesting, I executed it 10 minutes ago and it is still "working". I only get a lot of ^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@ under the command.

Answer (score 4):

For Mac Users: The `debug.keystore` file exists in `~/.android` directory. Sometimes, due to the relative path, the above mentioned error keeps on popping up.

Comment: I have the latest version of Android Studio (1.5.1) and my debug.keystore isn't there. I can't find it. Any pointers? I'm using OSX El Capitan.

Comment: Same problem with me, Have you solved it yet? @Rameez Hussain

Comment: This might be due to [SIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Integrity_Protection) introduced in OSX El Capitan and due to this, community support becomes weak as new concepts are introduced in El Capitan. You'll have to personally solve it, and community can only provide pointers for some time.

Answer (score 2):

For Mac/Linux debug keystore, the [Android docs](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth) have:

```
keytool -exportcert -list -v \
-alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore
```

But there is something that may not be obvious: If you put the backslash, make sure to do a `shift + return` in terminal after the backslash so that the second that starts with `-alias` is on a new line. Simply pasting as-is will not work.

Your terminal (if successful) will look something like this:

```
$ keytool -exportcert -list -v \
→ -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore
Enter keystore password:
```

The default debug password is: **android**

Side note: In Android Studio you can manage signing in:

**File > Project Structure > Modules - (Your App) > Signing**

Answer (score 1):

In macOS, open the Terminal and type below command

```
~/.android
```

It will navigate to the folder that containing Keystore file (You can confirm it with 'ls' command)

In my case, there is a file named 'debug.keystore'. Then type below command in the terminal from the ~/.android directory.

```
keytool -list -v -keystore debug.keystore
```

You will get the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

go to ~/.android
if there is no debug.keystore copy it from your project and paste it here then run command again.