# Showing 30 years of expiry date as by default debug.Keystore expiry is 365 days

Tags: java, android, web-services, sqlite

I am new to android.  Now I am trying to understanding signing an apk file.
I created one app and signed with a self signed certificate (with private keystore file) and everything is fine.
While I am trying to know more about `debug.keystore`.
I tried to sign apk with debug.keystore file when exporting apk in the Eclipse IDE.
At the last step I observed that the certificate expires on Fri Sep 19 15:02:42 IST 2042.

But the file is created on 26th Sep 2012.  When googling I observed that debug.keystore expires in 365 days.
But my debug.keystore is showing 30 years.
How is this possible? Some people say that it's the `Android Test QA certificate`, if so what is the difference?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4055893/1835231

Answer (score 0):

There is a parameter **-validity**  for the key tool:

http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#releasemode

You can specify there how many days the certificate should be valid.

Comment: Thanks p000ison, Actually what my doubt is,when iam signing my .apk with private debug .Keystore that is autogenerated, it is showing its expiry date for 30 years from present instead of 365 days

Comment: @user2644972 maybe you can generate your keystore manually? But I'm absolutly not sure, not very familiar with android development, only used the keytool for creating a self-signed ssh certificate :P