# 'Your project contains errors' for Windows Programmers

Tags: android, eclipse

Eclipse/Android has been working perfectly for months, and you suddenly get the error message, "Your project contains error(s), please fix them....".  But Eclipse has not flagged any errors. Try this:
Using Windows Explorer, search for the file named "debug.Keystore"   Look at the date/time of that file. It is the date/time of something called a Debug Certificate, which expires exactly 365 dayss (to the minute) from the date/time shown.  If it has expired, that is your problem.  Search Google for 'Debug Certificate Expired'  for further explanations and how to fix it.

Comment: Did you search before posting? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194808/debug-certificate-expired-error-in-eclipse-android-plugins

Comment: Is this suppost to be an Q&A, as you are kinda answering your own question.