# Including Java project output in Android deployment package

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm working on a learning Android project that happens to integrate with Toodledo. In that context, I have created a separate Java project, not depending on Android (so it's not an Android library project), that encapsulates addressing the Toodledo rest API. The last time I worked on the project is more than eight months ago, and at the time I was using OSX.

Since then, I repaved my machine, and I'm trying to get the application working again, this time on Windows, using Eclipse (as I was on OSX at the time).

However, although everything compiles just fine, I get an exception in the emulator on application launch, more specifically a *NoClassDefFoundError*, which is likely due to the fact that the project output from the Java project I reference is not included in the package (using a *project reference*, so I'm not referring to a jar).

What puzzles me is that I never experienced this kind of problem a year ago, and I'm totally in the dark why this is happening.

I don't think it has anything to do with this problem, but just for completeness' sake, I should mention that I use RoboGuice to load the dependencies in the application.

Any pointers would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the reason for the absence of the project output is caused by the fact that one way or another (probably it was just me) the Toodledo Rest API implementation project was using a higher version of the JDK (1.7) than the Android project (1.5).

This was indicated in the console with messages "Dx bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0033.0000)", but unfortunately I have been overlooking this for too long.

Googling on this led to this answer on StackOverflow:

[bad version in class file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847652/bad-version-in-class-file), which pointed me in the right direction. So issue solved as far as I'm concerned.