# Compile isolated java file

Tags: java, jar, compilation, compatibility, .class-file

I need to patch an old version of some Java software. The problem is that reconstructing the whole package at the old version would be very difficult because it is a very complex program.

I have the corrected source file. Is there any way to compile just this one file to a class file and then insert it into the jar, or do I have to have every single source file?

**UPDATE - How to do a Java Patch**

Using Elliott Frisch's answer I was able to make the patch. Here is the command line:

```
javac -target 1.5 -source 1.5 -cp original.jar;otherlib.jar CorrectedSource.java
```

So, to sum up. You specify the target version of Java and set the source to match, include the original jar (and any libs) as the classpath, then finally name the source code you want to compile. You can then take the resultant class files and insert them into the jar, replacing the old class files.

[To find out the target version of your class file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/698129/how-can-i-find-the-target-java-version-for-a-compiled-class)

Comment: Let me ask a question back: when you use a jar library in your application, do you need the source files of that jar to be able to compile java code that uses classes from that jar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should work if you recompile just that one file as long as

1. You use the same `-target <release>`, per `javac -help` that will *Generate class files for specific VM version* and I believe you need to match the original version.
2. You replace the version of the old class in the jar file with the new class file you generated in *1*. Please, **backup** the *original* Jar file first.

Comment: It is not working. I get lots of "cannot find symbol" errors for symbols which are defined in other source code files. Note from my question: trying to assemble the original set of source files would be very difficult. I need to compile/modify this ONE file without having all the source files in the project.

Comment: Add the original (compiled) jar to your `-cp` argument to `javac`.

Comment: ... and it works (complete solution in updated question)

Comment: Also, **assuming you don't have any changes which break binary compatibility**. For example, if you change the value of a static final field, the old classes won't see the new value. Same with method overloads.

Comment: @Elliott They may as well be. static final fields with primitive or string constants are inlined wherever they are accessed at compile time. Try it yourself if you don't believe me. Or read the Java specifications.

Answer (score 1):

1. Compile source file using `target <release>` to make sure it's the same version as the old jar was compiled to.
2. Rename `filename.jar` to `filename.zip`
3. Unzip `.zip` file
4. Replace `.class` file with new file
5. Rezip archive. It is okay to use compression. Make sure directory structure is the same as it was, and that you include the `META-INF` directory.
6. Rename file to `filename.jar` again.

**Note:** The checksum will be different. Some executable jars check for this, others don't. YMMV