# how to check the jdk version used to compile a .class file

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tool to read and display Java .class versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27065/tool-to-read-and-display-java-class-versions)

I'm trying to debug a

> "Bad version number in .class file'

error in java, is there a way for me to check which version the `.class` files are?

I'm using `JRE1.5.0_6`, but my `JDK` is version 1.6.0_13.

I'm compiling with compatibility mode set to 1.5 in eclipse which I thought would work...

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/698129/how-can-i-find-the-target-java-version-for-a-compiled-class

Comment: Check out [javadoc](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/ClassFile.doc.html) for more information on major and minor versions.

Answer (score 735, accepted):

You're looking for this on the command line (for a class called MyClass):

On Unix/Linux:

```
javap -verbose MyClass | grep "major"
```

On Windows:

```
javap -verbose MyClass | findstr "major"
```

You want the **major** version from the results. Here are some example values:

| Java Version | Major Version |
| --- | --- |
| 1.2 | 46 |
| 1.3 | 47 |
| 1.4 | 48 |
| 5 | 49 |
| 6 | 50 |
| 7 | 51 |
| 8 | 52 |
| 9 | 53 |
| 10 | 54 |
| 11 | 55 |
| 12 | 56 |
| 13 | 57 |
| 14 | 58 |
| 15 | 59 |
| 16 | 60 |
| 17 | 61 |
| 18 | 62 |
| 19 | 63 |
| 20 | 64 |
| 21 | 65 |

Comment: Alternatively, if you open the class file in a hex editor you can look at bytes 7 and 8. The number will map to the numbers given in the above answer. E.g. `00 2E` -> JDK 1.2 = 46 (0x2E hex). Useful if you don't have access to javap. ref: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file#General_layout

Comment: addendum: You can put -cp <jar> then the class so you can get it from and existing jar

Comment: I had to remove the ".class" in the command otherwise I got a message, "Error: Cannot find foo.class". So doing, "javap -verbose foo | grep "major"" worked. Just a heads up. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13356811/java-javap-errorcould-not-find-class

Comment: As Jim advises, for vi addicts: "vi MyClass" then "<Esc> :!xxd" then peep at byte 8; 0x31, 0x32, 0x33, 0x34, 0x35 stands for java 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 respectively. "<Esc> :q!" to exit vi.

Comment: So I was working on a project that uses amazon sdk. The project uses Java 1.7. If I check inside of the `MANIFEST.MF` of amazon sdk it says `Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_111` , but if I use `javap -verbose MyClass | grep "major"` it says `major version: 50` which means Java Version 6. This is confusing. Does that mean - even though it was compiled with 8 but it can run on 6?

Comment: So, this major version is in sequence? so for next Java 12 coming march will be 56 ?

Comment: The manifest Build-Jdk seems to be the JDK that made the jar file, which could be different from the JDK of the compiler.

Comment: [From inside your program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27065/tool-to-read-and-display-java-class-versions/58642950#58642950)

Comment: Just for information, On Windows we can use following command to find major version of jdk with which the class was compiled:

javap -verbose Xyz.class | findstr "major"

Comment: Could anybody add the major versions for Java >= 12?

Comment: what about an aar?

Answer (score 17):

Btw, the reason that you're having trouble is that the java compiler recognizes two version flags. There is -source 1.5, which assumes java 1.5 level source code, and -target 1.5, which will emit java 1.5 compatible class files. You'll probably want to use both of these switches, but you definitely need -target 1.5; try double checking that eclipse is doing the right thing.

Answer (score 9):

Free JarCheck tool [here](http://mindprod.com/products1.html#JARCHECK)

Answer (score 6):

You can try jclasslib:

https://github.com/ingokegel/jclasslib

It's nice that it can associate itself with *.class extension.

Answer (score 3):

Does the `-verbose` flag to your `java` command yield any useful info?  If not, maybe `java -X` reveals something specific to your version that might help?