# Java API to find out the JDK version a class file is compiled for?

Tags: version, java

Are there any Java APIs to find out the JDK version a class file is compiled for? Of course there is the javap tool to find out the major version as mentioned in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096148/how-to-check-the-jdk-version-used-to-compile-a-class-file). However I want to do it programmatically so that that I could warn the user to compile it for the appropriate JDK

Comment: The answers that involve reading bytes from a file seem quite uncivilized to me. There ought to be a way to get this information using Reflection, such as Foobar.class.getTargetVersion().

Answer (score 59, accepted):

```java
import java.io.*;

public class ClassVersionChecker {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
            checkClassVersion(args[i]);
    }

    private static void checkClassVersion(String filename)
        throws IOException
    {
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream
            (new FileInputStream(filename));

        int magic = in.readInt();
        if(magic != 0xcafebabe) {
            System.out.println(filename + " is not a valid class!");;
        }
        int minor = in.readUnsignedShort();
        int major = in.readUnsignedShort();
        System.out.println(filename + ": " + major + " . " + minor);
        in.close();
    }
}
```

The possible values are :

```
major  minor Java platform version 
45       3           1.0
45       3           1.1
46       0           1.2
47       0           1.3
48       0           1.4
49       0           5
50       0           6
51       0           7
52       0           8
53       0           9
54       0           10
55       0           11
56       0           12
57       0           13
58       0           14
59       0           15
60       0           16
61       0           17
62       0           18
63       0           19
```

ref : [The Java Virtual Machine Specification, Java SE 19 Edition](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se19/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.1)

Comment: Would it be possible to update this table or link to the official website where someone can find the versions past 14? Thank you

Comment: @ChristophSchreiber, the answer is updated

Answer (score 20):

basszero's approach can be done via the UNIX command line, and the "od(1)" command:

```
% od -x HelloWorldJava.class |head -2
0000000 feca beba 0000 3100 dc00 0007 0102 2a00
0000020 6f63 2f6d 6e65 6564 6163 642f 6d65 2f6f
```

"feca beba" is the [magic number](http://www.artima.com/insidejvm/whyCAFEBABE.html). The "0000 3100" is 0x31, which represents J2SE 5.0.

Answer (score 18):

On Linux, you can use the `file` command on a class file, which I found easiest for my use case. For example:

```
$ file Foo.class
Foo.class: compiled Java class data, version 50.0 (Java 1.6)
```

Comment: This works perfectly and is so much simpler than any of the other answers if you are  working in Linux.

Answer (score 10):

[Apache BCEL](http://jakarta.apache.org/bcel) provides this API:

```
JavaClass c = Repository.lookupClass("com.x.MyClass")
c.getMinor();
c.getMajor();
```

Answer (score 9):

This gets you the contents of the class file:

`MysteryClass.class.getResourceAsStream("MysteryClass.class")`

Then look at bytes 5-8 to get the minor and major version. A mapping between those numbers and the JDK releases can be found [here](http://blogs.oracle.com/darcy/entry/source_target_class_file_version).

Comment: Would the string argument need to be fully qualified?  getResourceAsStream("org/apache/foobar/Whatever.class")?

Comment: No, since you are using the class itself as base for getting the resource. You need the fully qualified name if you you can getResource methods of the ClassLoader instead of a class.

Answer (score 6):

Just read the class file directly. It's VERY easy to figure out the version. Check out the the [spec](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/ClassFile.doc.html#75883) and [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_%28file_format%29) and then try the code. Wrapping this code and making is more useful/pretty is left as an exercise. Alternatively, you could use a library like [BCEL](http://jakarta.apache.org/bcel/), [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/), or [JavaAssist](http://www.csg.is.titech.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/)

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ClassVersionTest
{
    private static final int JAVA_CLASS_MAGIC = 0xCAFEBABE;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream("Test.class"));
            int magic = dis.readInt();
            if(magic == JAVA_CLASS_MAGIC)
            {
                int minorVersion = dis.readUnsignedShort();
                int majorVersion = dis.readUnsignedShort();

                /**
                 * majorVersion is ...
                 * J2SE 6.0 = 50 (0x32 hex),
                 * J2SE 5.0 = 49 (0x31 hex),
                 * JDK 1.4 = 48 (0x30 hex),
                 * JDK 1.3 = 47 (0x2F hex),
                 * JDK 1.2 = 46 (0x2E hex),
                 * JDK 1.1 = 45 (0x2D hex).
                 */

                System.out.println("ClassVersionTest.main() " + majorVersion + "." + minorVersion);
            }
            else
            {
                // not a class file
            }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

As others have shown, it is easy enough to do by reading the first eight bytes of a class file. If you want a pre-built binary library, you can download one [here](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2009/07/java-finding-class-versions.html).

Answer (score 1):

JavaP does have an [API](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/6.0-JDK-Modules-sun/tools/sun.tools.javap.htm), but it's specific to the Sun JDK.

It's found in `tools.jar`, under `sun/tools/javap/Main.class`.

Answer (score 1):

I use this script in a batch file on windows, redirect the output and grep for the major number I am verifying for:

```
for /R %%f in (*.class) do (
"C:\Program Files\Java\JDK8\bin\javap" -v "%%f" | findstr major )
```

I run it as such:

```
verify.bat > versionResults.txt
```