# Get java version that was used to compile class

Tags: java

Is it possible somehow to get java version that was used to build class? Is there are any information compiled into class file? Possible there is some specific headers/footers or something like that.

Comment: The class files have a version number written in them.

Comment: @jarnbjo What makes you think that's the real question?  Knowing the actual compiler version seems of dubious use.  Knowing the JRE targeted by the code is obviously useful.

Comment: @Nathaniel: That's what user1501700 is asking for. If he means something else, he had lots of time to edit his question and I don't find the question particularly strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can find the version of JDK on which the class was compiled. Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293308/java-api-to-find-out-the-jdk-version-a-class-file-is-compiled-for).