# Find out which version of JDK a class was compiled in?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a class file, is it possible to check what version of the JDK it was compiled in?

The class file a servlet and it's being execute in a JSP page. In the JSP page, can I do a response.write of the class file JDK version that it was compiled in?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do this from inside the JVM.  You'll have to load the servlet class and read the version from the class file yourself.  See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1293308/658907).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:-

```
javap -verbose MyClass
```