# Cross Compilation in Java 13 and Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, cross-compiling, java-compiler-api, java-13

I want to load a Java version specific `JavaCompiler`.

This is how I take compiler instance currently:

```
JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
```

My aim is to compile a "user Java code" according to the Java version (Java 8 or Java 13) in which it is originally written.

I am building my whole source code in Java 8.

Hence `compiler` instance that I am getting will be Java 8 specific and I can not compile Java 13 code (correct me if I am wrong).

I have both Java 8 and Java 13 installed.

I read below statement from [this article](https://www.developer.com/java/data/an-introduction-to-the-java-compiler-api.html)

> The ToolProvider locates the default compiler in this case. It is also
>   possible to locate alternative compilers or tools by using service
>   provider mechanism.

Is there any way from which I can load Java version specific Java compiler?
Is there a workaround for it?

Or, if I build project using Java 13, can I then compile version-specific using `--target` or `--source` or `--release` arguments of Java 13 compiler?

Comment: Have you tried [getSourceVersions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/tools/Tool.html#getSourceVersions--) from Java 13 to see what versions the `JavaCompiler` supports? I don't know, but maybe if you just build your project using 13 then all previous versions will be supported, as is usually the case with compilers (to my knowledge).

Comment: actually, I have a project built in java 8, so I get only java 8 release and less with getSourcecVersions. Yes, maybe with java 13 build I can do. **BUT** I am aiming to get a compiler of java 13 from a project built with java 8. I will be trying with java 13 built.

Comment: Looks to me like you could extend class `ToolProvider` and override method `getSystemToolClassLoader()` - which was deprecated in JDK9, by the way - to return your custom class loader that loads the appropriate classes to perform the required compilation level. Of-course it is much easier to go backwards, i.e. you can compile Java 8 code with a Java 13 compiler, out of the box, as they say.

Comment: You don’t need to build your project using Java 13, the relevant point is on which version you *run* your code which uses the `JavaCompiler`.

Comment: @Abra, Thanks for the suggestion, can you provide me little code implementation about how exactly I can do this?

Comment: @Holger I run my code with Java 8, but I want the compiler to compile java 13 code, and also java 8 code. (maybe without changing the build version).

Comment: Then, you need a Java 8 compatible compiler implementation that supports compiling Java 13 code. The implementation shipped with JDK 8 doesn’t.

Comment: Your code may be compiled with JDK *n* and run with any JRE *m* (where *m≥n*). Thus  your runtime may not have any available compiler...  Also read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293308/java-api-to-find-out-the-jdk-version-a-class-file-is-compiled-for

Comment: The Eclipse compiler `ecj` still runs on Java 8 and latest builds support compiling Java versions 1.3 ... 14.

Answer (score 2):

So the final approach I used is:

**Step 1:**

Install **both** Java 8 and Java 13.

**Step 2:**

Make **Java 13 default**

both `javac` and `java`

**Step 3:**

**Build** the project in Java 13

**Step 4:**

Use Java 13 compiler to compile both Java 8 and Java 13 programs.

```
JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
```

It will give you Java 13 compiler.

**Step 5:**

While compilation I used the `--release` option.

You have to specify

`--release 13` for Java 13  (or u don't have too, as the compiler is Java 13 only)

and

`--release 8` for Java 8.

**Step 6:**   For executing the class files:

java 8 execution path for java 8 execution.

for ex:

```
path_to_java_8/java Helloworld
```

For Java 13 execution you can directly use `java` command as java 13 is default

```
java Helloworld
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this, but the following snippet might get you going:

```
JavaCompiler eclipseCompiler = ServiceLoader.load(org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.tool.EclipseCompiler.class).iterator().next();
```

To build your application you just need to add the following to your depedencies (given as maven coordinates):

```
<groupId>org.eclipse.jdt</groupId>
<artifactId>ecj</artifactId>
<version>3.21.0</version>
```

This will run on Java 8 and allows your application to compile for compliance 13.