# I am getting a "Bad version number in .class file" after my .jar file has already executed?

Tags: java

I have an odd one for you. I have a simple `.jar` installer program that I wrote in Eclipse on my MacBook Pro, running OS X 10.6.8. When I run the program in Windows 7, Vista and XP; works like a dream. However, when I try and run it in OS X 10.6.8, the program will execute like it should, however when it completes its execution I get the `"Bad version number in .class file"` error message.
     I ran `"java -version"` from the terminal and got

> java version "1.6.0_24"
>   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_24-b07-334-10M3326)
>   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.1-b02-334, mixed mode)

I also confirmed that Eclipse's compiler is using Java 1.6 for everything. As I have scoured the forums it looks like this error prevents the running of the program; but I have yet to see anything about the error showing up after the program has already run.

Comment: You may want to look at this question to confirm what version was generated: [how to check the jdk version used to compile a .class file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096148/how-to-check-the-jdk-version-used-to-compile-a-class-file) (remember, a JAR file is merely a zip file with a different extension, so you should be able to unzip the class files from it)

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks for the tip. I was unable to check the versions of the classes within the jar file. How would I go about unzipping the class files from the jar file? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Bad version number in .class file means the program was compiled in a newer version of JDK and you are attempting to run it in an older version of JVM.

E.G. you compiled using java 5.0 and are attempting to run using java 1.2.

Comment: Yeah, I read that. However when I checked what my machine was using for what version of Java it was running, it was the same as what I compiled it in. Do you know much about Eclipse? Could it be there is some hidden setting in there that would be causing this? I checked that it was indeed compiled using java 1.6. Any thoughts?

Comment: Hmm that is odd, have you tried re-installing JRE? Also you might want to check project properties, here is image:  http://i926.photobucket.com/albums/ad105/onelin/eclipse_project_java_compiler_setti.png

Comment: There was a Java 5.0 and Java 1.2, perhaps that is what you meant. ;)

Comment: I checked the project properties and they were all set to JRE 1.6, which is what OS X 10.6.8 has as the default. Thanks for the screenshot, was helpful : ). Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have some dependencies in the project? Like external .jar files (either as separate .jars or classes repacked to your jar)? They could be compiled with newer version of java (1.7 maybe?) or a bit newer version of 1.6 (on Windows there is 1.6.26 now - Mac version usually lags a bit).

Comment: The jar file I am compiling is only one .java file, 1 manifest file and one icon file that are all within the same Eclipse project src folder. Good to check on that though. Any other thoughts? Thanks,

Comment: Also, I am running Java 1.6.0_24 which is the most recent version for OS X. Thanks!