# Java : javap ERROR:Could not find .class

Tags: java, javap

In my system(Ubuntu 10.04) java is running fine but I am not able to run **javap** command
I have complile `Foo` class and *.class* file path is locate at
**/home/mahesh/java/opt**
when I execute
**javap -c Foo.class**
 I get following error message :
**ERROR:Could not find Foo.class**
Is there any need to set any environment variable or any thing else to resolve it.
my $PATH variable is target to:
**/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/lib/jvm/bin/**
Thank you.

Comment: Try `javap -c Foo -classpath /home/mahesh/java/opt`

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You just need to remove the `.class` extension.

Use the following command: `javap -c Foo`