# Error Page Exception in WebSphere

Tags: java, websphere

Getting exception in websphere

I already set java latest version.

my server version details

```
C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer> .\profiles\AppSrv02\bin\versionInfo.bat
WVER0010I: Copyright (c) IBM Corporation 2002, 2012; All rights reserved.
WVER0012I: VersionInfo reporter version 1.15.1.48, dated 2/8/12

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

IBM WebSphere Product Installation Status Report
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------


Report at date and time March 26, 2013 3:13:31 IST PM

Installation
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Product Directory        C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer
Version Directory        C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\properti
es\version
DTD Directory            C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\properti
es\version\dtd
Log Directory            C:\ProgramData\IBM\Installation Manager\logs

Product List
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

IBMJAVA7                 installed
BASE                     installed

Installed Product
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Name                  IBM WebSphere SDK Java Technology Edition (Optional)
Version               7.0.2.0
ID                    IBMJAVA7
Build Level           cf011240.02
Build Date            10/5/12
Package               com.ibm.websphere.IBMJAVA.v70_7.0.2000.20121005_1500
Architecture          x86-64 (64 bit)
Installed Features    IBM WebSphere SDK for Java Technology Edition 7

Installed Product
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Name                  IBM WebSphere Application Server
Version               8.5.0.1
ID                    BASE
Build Level           cf011242.02
Build Date            10/17/12
Package               com.ibm.websphere.DEVELOPERSILAN.v85_8.5.1.20121017_1724
Architecture          x86-64 (64 bit)
Installed Features    IBM 64-bit WebSphere SDK for Java
                      WebSphere Application Server Full Profile
                      EJBDeploy tool for pre-EJB 3.0 modules
                      Embeddable EJB container
                      Stand-alone thin clients and resource adapters

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

End Installation Status Report
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Please help me

```
    SRVE0260E: The server cannot use the error page specified for your application to handle the Original Exception printed below.

Original Exception:
Error Message: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: JVMCFRE003 bad major version; class=com/csdcsystems/amanda/web/viewmodel/LoginViewModel, offset=6
Error Code: 500
Target Servlet:
Error Stack:
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: JVMCFRE003 bad major version; class=com/csdcsystems/amanda/web/viewmodel/LoginViewModel, offset=6
     at java.lang.Class.forNameImpl(Native Method)
     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:170)
     at org.zkoss.lang.Classes.forNameByThread(Classes.java:268)
     at org.zkoss.lang.ImportedClassResolver.resolveClass(ImportedClassResolver.java:122)
     at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.PageImpl.resolveClass(PageImpl.java:478)
     at org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer.initViewModel(BindComposer.java:229)
     at org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer.doBeforeComposeChildren(BindComposer.java:142)
     at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.doBeforeComposeChildren(UiEngineImpl.java:875)
     at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreateChild0(UiEngineImpl.java:814)
     at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreateChild(UiEngineImpl.java:771)
     at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreate0(UiEngineImpl.java:680)
     at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreateChild(UiEngineImpl.java:742)
     at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreate0(UiEngineImpl.java:702)
     at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreate(UiEngineImpl.java:644)
     at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execNewPage0(UiEngineImpl.java:394)
     at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execNewPage(UiEngineImpl.java:316)
     at org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.DHtmlLayoutServlet.process(DHtmlLayoutServlet.java:214)
     at org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.DHtmlLayoutServlet.doGet(DHtmlLayoutServlet.java:135)
     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:575)
     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1224)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:774)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:456)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1032)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.dispatch(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:1384)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:193)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor.handleRequest(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:604)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1032)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3748)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:962)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:195)
     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:459)
     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:526)
     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:312)
     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:283)
     at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
     at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
     at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
     at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
     at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
     at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
     at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1814)
```

Comment: Check [this question and accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14926402/unsupportedclassversionerror-jvmcfre003-bad-major-version-in-websphere-as-7)

Comment: hi Rafael i already seen the link but my case it's not working .

Comment: I'm using 8.5 WebSphere java_home java 1.7 and eclipse compiler java 1.7 and inside WebSphere java 1.7

Comment: It really looks like you are compiling your code with a different Java version than running WebSphere. Add the jdk used by websphere to your eclipse environment and use it to compile. This should fix your error.

Comment: can i set external jre path inside websphere?