# Spring Transction is giving JVMCFRE003 bad major version; class=javax/inject/Provider, offset=6 err

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-transactions

I am trying to understand how spring declarative transaction works .For that purpose I have created one sample app .Here is the detail about this :
The spring configuration xml :

```
<context:component-scan base-package="*" />

<context:property-placeholder location="properties/database.properties"
order="1" ignore-unresolvable="true" ignore-resource-not-found="false" />
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource" destroy-method="close">
<property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
<property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
<property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
<property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
<property name="maxActive" value="${jdbc.maxActive}" />
<property name="maxIdle" value="#{new Integer('1')}" />
<property name="minIdle" value="#{new Integer('1')}" />
<!-- <property name="maxActive" value="#{T(java.lang.Integer).parseInt(${jdbc.maxActive})}" /> -->
<property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="${jdbc.defaultAutoCommit}" />
<property name="maxWait" value="#{new Integer('10000')}" />
<property name="removeAbandoned" value="#{new Boolean('true')}" />
<property name="logAbandoned" value="#{new Boolean('true')}" />
<property name="removeAbandonedTimeout" value="#{new Integer('55')}"/>
<property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1"/>
<property name="jdbcInterceptors"
value="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState;org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.StatementFinalizer;org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.StatementDecoratorInterceptor" />

</bean>
<bean id="sessionFactory"
class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">

<property name="dataSource">
<ref bean="dataSource" />
</property>

<property name="hibernateProperties">
<props>
<prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
</props>
</property>

<property name="annotatedClasses">
<list>
<value>org.satya.springhibernate.model.Stock</value>
<value>org.satya.springhibernate.model.AuditLog</value>
<value>org.satya.springhibernate.model.Account</value>
<value>org.satya.springhibernate.model.AuditLog</value>
<value>com.javahonk.di.bean.Person</value>
</list>
</property>
<property name="packagesToScan" value="org.satya.springhibernate.model" />
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean id="transactionManager"
class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```

**The PersonDAO class is like : **

```
@Component  
@Transactional  
public class PersonDAO extends CustomHibernateDaoSupport implements IPersonDAO {  
    @Override  
    public int insertUser(Person person) {  
        getHibernateTemplate().save(person);  
        return 0;  
    }  
}
```

**My main application **

```
   final AbstractApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(  
                    "classpath:/DataSource.xml");  

            IPersonDAO personDAO = applicationContext.getBean("personDAO",  
                    IPersonDAO.class);  
            Person person = new Person("Java", "Honk", "John st.", "NY", "NY",  
                    "USA");  

            // Insert user to the table 3 times:  
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {  
                personDAO.insertUser(person);  
            }
```

while try to run the application I am getting :

```
Jan 14, 2015 11:26:59 AM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@29d629d6: startup date [Wed Jan 14 11:26:59 IST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: JVMCFRE003 bad major version; class=javax/inject/Provider, offset=6
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:265)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:493)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$300(URLClassLoader.java:64)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$ClassFinder.run(URLClassLoader.java:892)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:284)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:414)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:643)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:300)
```

Thanks ,
Satya

Comment: This has nothing to do with Spring nor transactions. You have a jar in your classpath that isn't suitable for the java version you are using. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14926402/unsupportedclassversionerror-jvmcfre003-bad-major-version-in-websphere-as-7

Comment: Hi Deinum, thanks for the reply . How could I get which jar giving the problem .

Comment: The one that contains the class.

Comment: Hi Deinum, I am using org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager and the class is in the spring-jdbc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar.Which version of jar is suitable for this ,, am using jdk 6.

Comment: Have you actually read the stacktrace? `JVMCFRE003 bad major version; class=javax/inject/Provider, offset=6
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:265)`... As I stated it has nothing to do with spring, just basic java.

Comment: Hi Deinum, now am getting different exception :Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassFormatError: JVMCFRE074 no Code attribute specified; class=javax/transaction/SystemException, method=<init>()V, pc=0  
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassImpl(Native Method)  
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:265)  
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)  
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:493)

Comment: Don't use the crippled JEE jars from oracle, they work for compiling not runtime.

Comment: Ok ,, could you suggest any other version...