# Getting UnsupportedClassVersionError: JVMCFRE003 error when using reflection Library

Tags: java, reflection, websphere

I use the org.reflection library in my code, and i have this error when i run it.

```
Error 500: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: JVMCFRE003 version majeure incorrecte; classe=org/reflections/Reflections, décalage=6
```

My java compiler is 1.6, it is running on a v8.5 web sphere server.
And here's my dependency in my pom.xml :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
    <artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.12</version>
</dependency>
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

That API is built for 1.8, or at least it mentions 1.8 in the pom explicitly.
In general backwards compatibility is assured but forward is not.  You're using a 1.6 level JDK, which is really quite old at this point.

If sticking to that is a job requirement, you may be able to identify an older version of the library which works, or you may need to find or write a replacement.

But updating to a JDK from the last half decade really is not a bad idea at all.

Answer (score 0):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/14958377/3864977 for good information about the `JVMCFRE003` error.  Since this error is coming from `org.reflections.Reflections`, the `reflections` library is compiled at a higher Java level than your WebSphere 8.5.5 server is running on.  It appears that version 0.9.12 of `reflections` requires Java 8 - so you should either update your WebSphere installation to use Java 8, or downgrade the reflections dependency to whatever previous version matches your WebSphere java level.

Comment: How can i find which version match my Websphere java level? Should i just try with each version?

Comment: Well first you need to know what Java version you're using on WebSphere - checking the header in `SystemOut.log` is a quick way to do that.  It doesn't look java levels are documented for the reflections library - but I've just checked and the previous release 0.9.11 is compatible with Java 7.

Comment: I didn't change the version of reflection. What i did is : 
i changed the default jdk of my server to 1.8, and it worked with reflection 0.9.12