# jax-ws + tomcat 5.5 where (local server + jdk 1.6 = works) but (dev server + jdk 1.5 = does not work)

Tags: jax-ws, java-6, tomcat5.5, java-5

I have a web service working in my local test environment but not on a development server.

My local test environment characteristics:

- JDK 1.6 is installed on my machine but the JDK compliance is 1.5 (specified in MyEclipse project)
- Tomcat 5.5

My development server environment characteristics:

- JDK 1.5
- Tomcat 5.5

I do not have any control over upgrading Tomcat on the development server. Is there a solution for the exception below? The jax-ws ri jar files that I downloaded are version 2.2.8 which were built using JDK 1.6 (I checked a manifest file). Is this the reason for this problem? How can I workaround it? Is there an earlier version of jax-ws ri jar files that were built on JDK 1.5?

Any ideas would be appreciated.

I am getting the following exception when I try to start my application in Tomcat on the development server:

```
Feb 28, 2014 10:55:29 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1319)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1181)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3617)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4104)
at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1175)
at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:510)
at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doGet(HTMLManagerServlet.java:104)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:689)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:252)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:178)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:126)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:105)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:148)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:856)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11Protocol.java:744)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:527)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:80)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:684)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Feb 28, 2014 10:55:29 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Skipped installing application listeners due to previous error(s)
```

Comment: As a quick test, I downloaded JDK 1.5 and set Tomcat in the local test environment to use JDK 1.5 and I got the same exception above. So, at least I've been able to reproduce it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the Java Virtual Machine attempts to read a class file and determines that the major and minor version numbers in the file are not supported, is *higher* than the installed version of the JVM.

Change the version to [JAX-WS 2.2.5](https://jax-ws.java.net/2.2.5/). This version was compiled with `1.5.0_16-b02`.

Comment: Tomcat uses JVM 1.5.0_11-b03. Do you know which version of JAX-WS was compiled with 1.5.0_11-b03 or older?

Comment: I am confused because JAX-WS 2.2.5 was compiled with a version of the jdk that is newer than the jdk used by tomcat... which was the original problem. I don't see how this should work.

Comment: jax-ws 2.2.8 was built with 1.6.0_41

Comment: jax-ws 2.2.5 was built with 1.5.0_16-b02

Comment: tomcat uses jvm 1.5.0_11-b03

Comment: both jdk versions used to build jax-ws 2.2.8 and 2.2.5 are newer than what tomcat uses

Comment: Should work. The Java version in the class file is the same, regardless of the level of update (`_XX`) or build (`bXX`). See more in http://stackoverflow.com/q/1096148/870248