# wrong java version? Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

Tags: java, maven, jar, backwards-compatibility

I run a jar file on an external server. the jar-file is compiled by mvn on my local machine. the external server has java 1.7 installed, so I needed to explicitly tell maven to compile to java 1.7 because on my local machine I already use java 1.8.

However, I still get the following error when running the jar:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: io/package/name/Launcher : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:643)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:73)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:212)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:323)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:268)
Could not find the main class: io.package.name.Launcher. Program will exit.
```

According to other threads `Unsupported major.minor version 51.0` means that java 7 is expected (*update*: this is wrong. actually the error means that the system where I try to execute the jar can not handle the provided version which is 51 which equals java 7 / 1.7. so this implies that the system runs an even lower version (java 1.6?)). However, I double checked the compiled classes and they indeed should be compatible to java 7. but maybe I did something wrong when checking. I checked by using a HexEditor as explained here: [how to check the jdk version used to compile a .class file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096148/how-to-check-the-jdk-version-used-to-compile-a-class-file#comment35607560_1096159)

Here is a screenshot showing the 7th and 8th byte of Launcher.class. The `0x33` is 51. And 51 means that the class file is compatible with Java 7 (according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/1096159/973158).

A `java -version` on the server yields:

```
java version "1.7.0_79"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (rhel-2.5.5.1.el6_6-x86_64 u79-b14)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)
```

And this is how I tell maven to compile to java 1.7 in pom.xml

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

What am I doing wrong? Could it be that there is some sort of cache on the server which still holds an old version of the class which was compiled to java 1.8?

**FINAL UPDATE:**

my code actually was java 1.7 compatible, however, I wasn't aware of the fact that java 1.6 was required. my bad.

Comment: How exactly are you running the jar file on the server? It seems to me more likely that somehow you're running Java 6 on the server - that's what the error message suggests. (If the problem was that it was compiling to Java 8, you'd get an error message about version 52.)

Comment: the server is actually a cluster which runs [slurm](http://slurm.schedmd.com/). there I need to create so called job-files which are similar to bash scripts. my job-file looks like this: http://i.imgur.com/Er9mbTA.png

Comment: I suggest you run `java -version` *in the job file*... I suspect you'll find that it doesn't use the same version of Java that you're seeing from the shell when logging in directly.

Comment: that would be mean. okay, so now I did `java -version` in the job-file. will see what it will come up with. i have to wait some time, because the job is in the queue now.. will report back.

Comment: A fine opportunity to upgrade the cluster to java 1.7.

Comment: :D it's the vienna scientific cluster... i think they won't agree.
anyway, it's strange that in the main shell `java -version` yields 1.7, and that the actual java-version which is used when I execute a job is different. but please note that this is not confirmed, yet... my job is still in the queue, so i am still waiting.

Comment: update: `java -version` from inside the job file yields `java version "1.6.0_34"`. so you guys were right. have to port my code now.