# Why is my @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") ignored?

Tags: java, javac, suppress-warnings

Why is Javac ignoring my `@SuppressWarnings` annotation in the code below?

```
@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = true, timeout = 10)
public List<Item> findAllDue() {
    Query query = getSession().createQuery("from Item item where item.status = :status");
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<Item> list = query.setString("status", ItemState.MY_STRING_STATUS).list(); //This is line 43.  yes, I know it can be an Enum instead
    return list;
}
```

After compiling with Xlint, here is the warning:

```
Warning:(43, 106) java: unchecked cast
  required: java.util.List<com.company.domain.Item>
  found:    java.util.List
```

The code builds successfully with this warning.  It probably doesn't matter, but this is Spring 4 and Hibernate 4.

**Update, based on comments:**

I attempted to edit my example for a general case rather than providing company specific code.   For those quick to downvote, as supporting evidence: here is the actual output from my editor and the actual code, using Java 7 with the company name redacted.

[image: editor image]

Below is the terminal output, without using an editor, but javac with ant:

[image: terminal output]

Comment: This may be an obvious question, but are you sure that warning is on the same line as the suppression? Could it be complaining about `return list;`? After all, `List<Item>` isn't covariant with `List<Lease>`.

Comment: What version of Java?

Comment: @AndyTurner - that was a typo.   Updated question with the actual return type.  Can someone explain the downvote?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis please take a look at my answer.

Comment: @bphilipnyc could you check tha Java version you are using to compile? you can use : `javap -verbose MyClass | findstr "major"` on the command line as explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096148/how-to-check-the-jdk-version-used-to-compile-a-class-file

Comment: `javap -verbose LeaseDaoImpl.class | grep major` yields
 `major version: 51`

Comment: @bphilipnyc does any answer helped you?

Comment: Similar case but on Java 17. I moved the annotation from the affected field/method to the class level. Not ideal, but made javac stop complaining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update:

This is a javac bug that affects the versions: 6u51, 7u21, 8. That was reported and fixed here:[JDK-8016099](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8016099).

Other related reports are:  [JDK-8022144](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8022144) and [JDK-8016636](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8016636) but they are all marked as duplicate to the first one.

That was fixed in 1.8.0u65.

Comment: [Spring 4 requires at least Java 6](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/new-in-4.0.html).

Comment: @AndyTurner thanks, I changed my answer after some search

Comment: Give me a bit of time - need to try with Java 8

Comment: After updating my project, verified corrected in 1.8.0_71.

Answer (score 0):

TL; DR: **Declare the evaluated static String before the method as a workaround.**

I am able to clear the warnings in a rather unorthodox way and it *may be a bug* - or some ridiculous "feature" :).

The examples that follow describe the behavior.  Each one uses the `@SuppressWarnings` annotation.

If I use the evaluated String as in (a), no warning is shown. 
If I declare the String prior to the method call as in (b), no warning is shown.

Making the string a private member in the same class has no effect and still produces the compiler warning (b).

[image: some examples]

If we evaluate the constant first, it produces no warning, as in (d):

[image: workaround]

Comment: Yeah that very much looks like an IDE bug.

Comment: No, it's the same on the command line (as shown in the question)

Comment: For future readers, if you're coming across this post and upgrading isn't a possibility, this is still a valid workaround.