# Android Pre Dex: [XYZ.jar] Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/dexer/Main

Tags: cordova, dex, invocationtargetexception, unsupported-class-version, phonegap-cli

I am working on PhoneGap framework and trying to load old project of phonegap in IntelliJ 14.

When I load project, continuously getting the error :

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
.
.
.
.
.
.

Android Pre Dex: [xyz.jar] Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/dexer/Main
.
.
.
.
.
.
```

I have tried with below ways :

- Android SDK version tried with API 19 , 23 and with latest one as well
- Have tried on MAC and Windows both
- Project is getting compiled on the system from where it was created already
- Project is not based on Gradle.

If someone has face this issue, then please let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have observed through various blogs and find the answer is that,

I need to set my java compiler version and target version 1.8 as '52.0.0' is pointing to the J2SE8. Ref from below mentioned URL :
[how to check the jdk version used to compile a .class file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096148/how-to-check-the-jdk-version-used-to-compile-a-class-file)

Changed the Java compiler version and that has worked.

Hope so this works for the same problem.