# java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError for running Jena API on Tomcat 8

Tags: java, tomcat, jvm, jena

I am deploying Spring application on Tomcat 8 server. The application uses Jena API from this [maven repository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.jena/jena-tdb/3.0.0). When I open the application in browser, it shows the following message (the same application can be opened without any problem when I do not use Jena API):

> HTTP Status 500 - Handler processing failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:
>   org/apache/jena/query/QueryExecutionFactory : Unsupported major.minor
>   version 52.0 (unable to load class
>   org.apache.jena.query.QueryExecutionFactory)

I tried to solve this problem by changing the version of Java for Tomcat 8. I opened `sudo nano /etc/init/tomcat.conf` and changed JAVA_HOME:

```
env JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
```

Then I restarted Tomcat 8 server and redeployed my application, but the same problem still exists. In fact I noticed that for some reason JRE 7 appears in the log message when starting the server:

> May 07, 2016 5:26:11 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: Java Home:
>   /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre May 07, 2016 5:26:11 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: JVM
>   Version:           1.7.0_80-b15 May 07, 2016 5:26:11 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: JVM
>   Vendor:            Oracle Corporation

I am not sure if this might be a possible reason of why the problem is not fixed. Any solution is highly appreciated.

P.S. I know that `java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError` happens because of a higher JDK during compile time and lower JDK during runtime. So, do I understand correctly that Jena API was compiled with lower JDK?

Comment: please confirm using: `echo $JAVA_HOME`

Comment: @victor sosa: `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64`

Comment: Which Linux ? Check the initscript

Comment: Please set `/etc/init/tomcat.conf` to `env JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64`; JAVA_HOME environment variable should be set to the base path of the JDK.

Answer (score 3):

Actually as far as I can see in the jar that you provide, the major version of `Jena` is `52` which means that it has been **compiled with java 8**, I believe that your problem is more due to the fact that you run tomcat with **java 7**

For more details about how to know the version of a class, please refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1096159/1997376)

To indicate `Tomcat` which `JDK` to use, you need to set the `JAVA_HOME` to the path of a `JDK` not a `JRE` by doing this export `JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle`. More details [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/setup.html)

Comment: Do you know how to run Tomcat with java 8? As I explained in my answer I tried to change Tomcat's java from `/etc/init/tomcat.conf`, however it seams that there is another configuration that I had to change.

Comment: you need to set JAVA_HOME to the path of the jdk not the JRE, so try this env JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will check it, recompile the project and let you know if it worked.

Comment: I changed JAVA_HOME  in `/etc/init/tomcat.conf` to `/usr/bin/jvm/java-8-oracle´, but when I launch Tomcat from Eclipse, it outputs `May 07, 2016 7:01:04 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre`. Why? (obviously that the problem still persists).

Comment: what do you get when you launch "which java"? Have you tried to launch it manually using startup.sh as described in the like that I provide in my answer?

Comment: The problem was with Eclipse settings of Tomcat 8. Though I was changing tomcat.conf, still the version 1.7 was used due to Server settings in Eclipse. I will accept your answer if you add this detail.

Comment: if you find it by yourself simply add your answer and accept it